# Practical effects of the October 2023 layoff

Tags: discussion, announcements, stack-exchange-team, company

I hope that by now you’ve all had a chance to read and digest [the announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393791/community-notice-october-2023-layoff-announcement) and the [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/10/16/stack-overflow-company-announcement-october-2023/) about today’s layoff.

This was not an easy decision to make, nor is this an easy conversation to have. At the end, if you squint, I hope you’ll see the faint glimmer of a silver lining. But we have work to do before we get to that point.

#### On October 16th, 2023, Stack Exchange laid off roughly 28% of its workforce. This follows a [previous lay-off of 10% in May](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389060/).

Among those impacted this time were two highly valued members of the Community team.

While we are respecting the privacy of those impacted, I want to take a moment to say that the folks we laid off were **not** let go on the basis of poor performance. On the contrary, they are some of the best folks I have ever had the chance to work with. These are attractive hires, solid candidates, and affable, talented people. We’re grateful to have had the chance to work with them. They have our respect, and they deserve yours as well. I hope that we can count on you to do everything possible to ease their transition, beginning by not speculating as to who was cut and ‘why’. They deserve some privacy as they get focused on their next moves.

It is impossible to ignore the fact this action will have impacts on the community. Now that you have a better sense for what took place, it’s time to talk about the effects that this change will have on the community itself, and your participation here.

##### Our commitment to the community remains unchanged.

I want to start by dispelling any concerns that our plan involves contractions in the community, closing any site, or ramping down participation. **The community isn’t going anywhere.**

Community is among the most reliable cornerstones of the place – the essence of what makes this company what it is. Our intent to support the community using whatever resources we have available is unwavering.

Our commitment to ensuring the community is maintained, however, does *not* mean the community will be unaffected by today’s changes. It will be affected, and you deserve to know exactly how.

##### Our responses to you will be temporarily disrupted.

Everyone in the company will be involved in managing this transition. Because every team in the company was impacted by these cuts, every single team’s workflow is going to change. You can reasonably expect some delays as we adjust.

##### Projects undergoing active work may change scope or be canceled.

Stack Exchange has many projects in the oven at any given time, ranging from days to months in length. The scope of many of these short-term projects will change.

Longer-term projects that are more piecemeal in nature, such as time spent servicing requests for new tools, may also be impacted and responsiveness may slow down. My commitments during the recent moderator action negotiations remain intact, and we will continue to honor them.

At the same time, there may be a couple of very exciting product features to announce - including the potential return of one or two that were previously sunset that you might feel strongly about.  We’re seeing some positive signs around uptake for our new OverflowAI features, and today’s actions will allow us to be more strategic and to narrow our focus as we move forward. Expect to see a continued focus on OverflowAI as we build it toward commercial viability.

##### Short-term priorities may shift towards reliability and maintenance.

It’s important to us that the sites continue to function as designed. Like I said, the community isn’t going anywhere. That means we’ll still prioritize bug-fixes as usual, and maintain our uptime. Any reduction in our work throughput will come from other areas of product development.

#### If you’ve got questions, put ‘em in answers. One question per answer, please.

I’m expecting this post to spark *many* questions, and we’ll do our best to answer as many as we can. If we answer that something is confidential, please don’t take that as an opportunity to speculate. Again, out of respect for anyone impacted, we are not able to answer any questions about individual employees. We may remove content that violates the privacy of people impacted here.

To make this easier to manage, please ask **only one question per answer**.
In terms of answering questions here, the following are designated as official company spokespersons. Any other person answering or discussing below is not working with or answerable to them and those answers should probably be regarded as unofficial and not authoritative. Our designated spokespeople are:

- [Prashanth Chandrasekar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/579126/prashanth-chandrasekar) (CEO)
- [Lily Toy](https://stackoverflow.co/company/leadership/lily-toy) (Chief Legal Officer)
- [Jody Bailey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1196463/jody-bailey) (CTO)
- [Philippe Beaudette](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/936316/philippe) (VP, Community)

Others may be designated if needed but they will be introduced and added to this list by one of these people, if so.

#### Final thoughts

Today is a pretty sucky day for all of us, but particularly for those who are leaving us. I wouldn’t presume to imagine how they’re feeling, but I know it can’t feel good. We’re all going to miss our colleagues, and we’re asking for your understanding as we sort out how we move forward. But one of the most important things that we do now is to honor our impacted teammates and the  gifts they brought with them, and we do that by letting them know that their work and contributions will live on, and they will forever be a part of the story of this place. We were honored to work with them. We owe them a debt of gratitude, and we wish them the very best.

Comment: The affected CMs have been in the Tavern to talk about what happened and have been conspicuously removed from the Meta list of CMs (as well as the more subtle effects like disappearing staff/mod badges), so it's not exactly a secret (and, given their public-facing role, it couldn't be). But, I do think it is difficult not to speculate about how these particular individuals were chosen and what it means for company strategy, given the kind things you have to say about them and their intimate connections to the community as users and former moderators prior to their staff roles.

Comment: @BryanKrause I can understand that feeling, and the desire for clarity around those choices.  Unfortunately, I'm not going to talk about why particular folks were selected and others weren't, other than to say that none of them were performance issues.  I would happily work with any of them again.

Comment: "**The community isn’t going anywhere**." Well, they _might_ go somewhere else if you keep firing all their beloved community managers and other Q&A teams... everyone left on the Community team now has, what, 3 years of experience with this community or less?

Comment: Thank you @Philippe. I think it’s important to recognize that the U.S. economy and tech sector in particular is dealing with layoffs across the board the last few years (including double-digit percentage layoffs at my company recently). This is the economic reality in the U.S. in 2023 and it may get worse. Tech layoffs are at 240k just this year up 50% from 2022.

Comment: @java-addict301 That's... not really relevant; 99% of the "tech layoffs of 2022/2023" are from FAANG or FAANG-adjacent companies who over-hired during the pandemic to build capacity for remote working. Stack Overflow already worked fine w/ remote workers and also does not offer cloud products that are impacted by significantly more users stuck at home.

Comment: TylerH, no..... we have more than that... Slate, Jnat, Cesar.... and that's right off the top of my head.  Not to mention the community knowledge entrenched in other teams (Yaakov, for isntance).

Comment: @Philippe As this has had a significant impact on the most visible members of the CM team itself, who will be taking the leadership of responding to the many comments that  the community has about this announcement to maintain community trust that the company is at least listening to them?

Comment: Practical effect: The good years are over. SO is sliding since many years and the company together with the community didn't find the right answers while the resources were still there. Now resources are dwindling but acceptance for change might be higher (on both sides). It may get better or even worse.

Comment: @user1937198 The company's "designated spokespeople" are listed in the post you're commenting on.

Comment: @Randal'Thor and of those spokespeople,  other than philippe, which has posted to meta in the last 6 months?

Comment: Some 400k tech jobs lost in 2022 + 3/4 of 2023... (src: Layoffs.fyi)

Comment: as a company, you decide which member of the community team leaves or stays, but you don't get to decide what the community does. Your "The community isn’t going anywhere" seems quite a bold statement to make

Comment: How did you spend [$85 million in three years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351385/230855)? This company used to make [$70 million a year](https://twitter.com/gortok/status/1218174860205199365).

Comment: @Lamak It's double-sided on top of that : I read "*The community isn't going anywhere*" as in "*the community is cornered against the wall, it will be dead*" x). It's a bad (or excellent ) choice of words.

Comment: @Philippe Yesterday there were some amazingly quick responses to questions asked here in the answers. Thank you so much for the quick responses on those. I assume you'll be messenger for most answers, and there's a lot to answer-- But can you set expectations for when folks might expect responses on other questions that have been asked?

Comment: Designated spokesperson Prashanth Chandrasekar, [last seen more than a month ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/579126/prashanth-chandrasekar).  Hmm...

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones That's not a big problem for me. I never understood what the CEO wants to say anyway. With Philippe I feel like I might be able to have a meaningful conversation. With "...it's to better meet the demands of our users, customers, and partners as part of this commitment to product innovation and the continued momentum of OverflowAI both for Stack Overflow for Teams and on our public platform" for example I cannot really interact.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones - [Last heard from, nearly 3 years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/579126/prashanth-chandrasekar?tab=activity)

Comment: @AMtwo- I just posted another tranche of answers, and I'll do another hopefully later today.  It's a lot to write :)

Comment: @Philippe this question is up for a couple days, now, and so far there is no sign of Mr. Prashanth Chandrasekar showing up to address the community's questions.

Comment: What really pisses me off is that one day you have massive layoffs, the next day you launch some "new colors" initiative which literally achieved nothing but making all sites less readable. So you have a whole team engaged in a project for the sole purpose of actively making the sites worse, essentially just digging pits and filling them up again. And then you wonder why the company is doing poorly.

Comment: @Lundin Hi! I am **not** a designated spokesperson, so consider my response unofficial. I understand you don't like the colors update, and you're entitled to that opinion. But this project has been worked on for a while, including by people who just lost their jobs, in order to make the sites more accessible. Please don't devalue their work by claiming it had the "sole purpose of actively making the sites worse". That's blaming this horrible situation on talented and well-meaning individuals who want to make the sites better for everyone, and I'm sure such blame was not your intention.

Comment: @T.Sar quick look [here](https://stackexchange.com/users/16260110/prashanth-chandrasekar?tab=accounts) clearly showing the CEO has no interest in the sites. That is fine, he is a very busy person. What strikes me odd is why there is list of four spokespeople when it's beyond obvious there is actually only one. Can't see the goal in listing more people, who won't engage. (one of them doesn't even have account in Stack Exchange)

Comment: @balpha I also don't like the change, but I'm not expert in  accessibility so can only hope it's indeed more accessible. However, as usual the basic and greatest mistake is lack of transparency and communication between the company and us, the users. While it [was announced in advance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386102/accessibility-update-colors), it's empty announcement, lacking actual details or screenshots of what's going to be changed. I believe if they would have shown the changes before, feedback could improve that. But alas, when considering us as noise, it won't happen.

Comment: [cont]. Why noise? Actions speak for themselves, and the greatest proof is removing the last bridges between the company and the community, aka the most active and known staff members who acted as bridge. So yes, this is super annoying, and might break any confidence one might have in the company. But bottom line you're right that it's not related to the colors change, it's way more fatal than that.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry I may not agree with all of that, but it's an understandable impression to have. I was merly objecting to the word "purpose" in that other comment. It's one thing to criticize decisions (there's enough reasons to do that), or to state opinions about changes, but it's another thing to imply that some people (actual human beings who are far away from any layoff decisionmaking) actively set out with the plan "let's make SE a little worse today".

Comment: @balpha totally agree, and I was reprimanded once, think by Adam, for calling a new feature "half baked" and insulting those working on it, and it led me to realize I was indeed mistaken. The people who build and maintain SE are **awesome**, each and every one. Including you. So, thanks!

Comment: @Lundin I am here since 2012, they did it always so.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones What could he say? I think the company needs about 10-50 employee, about 80% of them can be offshore remote guy. But they have about a thousand. I think, 38% is still a little, they could safely fire 90%.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones Search on the company employee on linkedin. I think, this applies: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WSatPoD2W-o Sad thing is that it is probably no one's fault.

Comment: @peterh -I can assure you that we have nowhere near 1000 employees.  Closer to half of that number, I believe.

Comment: @Philippe Thanks. :-( I am sad on that, and the most important thing, what also Icahn admitted in the video: this situation was the fault of no one.

Comment: @balpha Although the constant and completely meaningless UI changes _is_ about digging a pit and filling it up again, it doesn't really matter which busy-work project we speak of. Take the whole AI nonsense - I don't even want to know how many are working with digging/filling those pits. Surprise: turns out all of these nonsensical projects cost money.

Comment: Of the 4 spokespeople mentioned in this post, I only see Philippe actually responding to anything here. What was the point in nominating the other 3 if they are not going to contribute?

Comment: @DavidG - [Phillippe answered that in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393806/practical-effects-of-the-october-2023-layoff?cb=1#comment1317589_394018), I read this as the other 3 were never intended to be user facing spokespeople, make of that as you wish

Comment: @Sayse That link doesn't work and I can't see any comment relating to that?

Comment: @DavidG - [Its on CGCampbells answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394018/298072) if that helps

Comment: I just reluctantly came here for a search because I couldn't find the topic I wanted on Codidact and what do find? Chaos again! I [asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342241/if-stack-exchange-ceased-operations-tomorrow-where-would-you-go-for-qa) about this on Meta almost 4 years ago. It seems this site is dying and I hope all this knowledge and talent migrates to somewhere we can all find it.

Comment: @TecBrat Maybe dying, but if so at a very slow rate. Kind of painful to watch. Especially if the feeling is that quite a number of unnecessary mistakes contributed along the road.

Comment: @TecBrat (Off-topic, but check out the recently launched https://proposals.codidact.com/ similar to Area 51 here. If there's a topic you are interested in but no community matches, you can make a draft for a new site and until launch ask questions that would match the proposed site it in "Incubator Q&A". So you can literally ask about any topic.)

Comment: We have a few questions that are approaching one-week old without an answer from the staff. Can we get some love for those?

Comment: @Philippe I am really disappointed (but also, not surprised) that despite giving an extensive framework for answering questions with designated spokespeople, etc... there have been very few answers provided to questions. There are "Great Answers™" that have gotten no response at all. If the SLT is wondering why the community is not as cozy with the company as we used to be, I think y'all should consider that from our side, this is essentially gaslighting by the people in power (the company). When community members leave this abusive relationship, SLT shouldn't be surprised.

Comment: @Philippe There are still several questions open waiting for answers. Please try to address then when possible.

Comment: @Philippe any updates on those questions here?

Comment: `Our commitment to the community remains unchanged.` Well, except for the salaries we paid to CMs (:

Answer (score 262):

> Community is among the most reliable cornerstones of the place – the essence of what makes this company what it is. Our intent to support the community using whatever resources we have available is unwavering.

Then why, over the past two firings ([and previous rounds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342031/332043)), have you eliminated the CMs and other employees  who were among the largest advocates for the community and who, in some of the worse periods, were the only communication channel with the company?

Comment: Not just the CMs.  And in fact, this time around the CM team was hit much lighter than many other teams, because of the critical role that it plays here. But ultimately,  decisions needed to be made to reach a certain target, and there was no way to protect the CM team entirely. Nobody has more respect for the CM team than I do.  I'm feeling the cuts very personally today.  I was blessed to work with them, and once they're on my team, that's forever, and I will celebrate every time I see them.

Comment: @Philippe You're missing the point (and the "CMs **and other employees**" bit). The point is that over the past few years, the company has fired many of the outward-facing staff members who actually believed in, and advocated for the community. With this last round of employees being fired, the list of remaining community advocates (that, more importantly, also has the faith of the community) has shrunk. You claim to believe in the community, but we're left with a continuously shrinking list of staff members that both engage with, and more importantly, understand and are willing to discuss

Comment: how to improve the situation for the community.

Comment: @Philippe "and once they're on my team, that's forever" - forever? You mean until they're laid off. I'm really sorry, but your **actions** (of the company which you're key part of) conflict with the nice words.

Comment: "Nobody has more respect for the CM team than I do. I'm feeling the cuts very personally today." And yet, they were made, and (by your own admission) not for performance-related reasons.

Comment: @Philippe We can understand that decisions have been made to reach a certain target. That's a given. What we don't understand is what this "target" was set this way. However, it is the company that sets those targets themselves. Why the target was set in such a manner that it _forces_ CM's to be removed makes one wonder if the target is actually in line with the stuff that is actually needed to make this site work, or is more focused on "profits" here and now.

Comment: We can be angry about this (I sure am), but it's disingenuous and potentially insulting to call it a "firing." Generally, employees at fault get fired; folks who get laid off would probably never describe it as getting fired.

Comment: @Stuckat1337 You're assuming bad faith here. The dictionary definition of "to fire" [does not assign blame](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fire): "to remove someone from their job, either because they have done something wrong or badly, **or as a way of saving the cost of employing them:**", i.e. precisely what happened here. The US quietly assigning legal blame based on which word is used is not something I was aware of. Besides, it has clearly gotten the point across, and that's good enough for me. I don't really care what specific semantics the US attaches to it

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Giving the benefit of the doubt, companies can't survive if they aren't making money, so layoffs may (at least sometimes) be *necessary* to avoid the alternative of the whole company going down and *everyone* losing their jobs. This, of course, doesn't mean that some layoffs aren't driven by greedy capitalism. But still, it seems better to focus on the choice of *who* to lay off (or what they're spending money on).

Comment: @Philippe This is the **highest voted community question, and deserves a straight answer**. In your comment above, you make tangential statements (first two sentences), hand-waving ("*no way to protect the CM team entirely*" when the question is just about two specific people), and for the rest of it, you change the topic to your personal feelings about losing them. (1/2)

Comment: @Philippe (2/2) Elsewhere you suggest other members of the team CM are up to the challenge, which is also hand-waiving because the question is not about them, but about the trust and rapport slowly built up with incredible effort that's now gone. **Please directly address the question** of the extent to which the choice of people to be laid took into consideration how close they were to the community.

Comment: @Philippe I think there's the big picture here. In the last rounds of downsizing, we lost Shog9, Nicholas, Robert, Cat and V2blast, all of whom have had a long history with the community. We also lost Salmon - who was a good CM *but* like most of the current team, didn't *quite* have the visibility. . Building trust takes time, and it seems the average shelflife of a CM is ... about 5 years before involuntary termination. We've... two CMs left with a history on the network pre-employment  - and the company pretty much has made it impossible to get any more.

Comment: I mean, it pretty much is a hostile workplace if you're basically going to get randomly offered up as tribute. And even if we survive, a lot of folks passionate about the network - are and do remember many of these choices. I don't want particularly to see anyone lose their jobs but whoever made these choices on who had to be cut chose, and consistantly chooses poorly, and in ways that hurt *us* - which I feel is unacceptable. If the community matters, perhaps in the process of downsizing the *impact* of staff should be a concern. We've already lost *many* in the company who were

Comment: great communicators, and had built up trust over years. I'm taking it *personally* cause I'd been loudly, if not effectively advocating for *more* community hires in the company, yet there seems to be just a reversion to the same behaviours we saw before. Promises not kept - key folks getting downsized because "we need to survive". We literally had the exact pattern leading to having only 4 community managers left. We don't trust the company to have our best interests because we've seen *exactly* where this leads, and its not good.

Answer (score 259):

The community isn't going anywhere isn't true. We have lost chunks of the community over time and they never came back.

It's worth considering that the biggest project that's set back is *trust*. Trust built over years - lost, points of contact we were familiar with no longer exist.

If you do manage to get out of the rut you're in now, the next future CM or SRE is going to ask themselves - 'Do I have a future here' in a company that seems to have a revolving door even for great employees.

Unlike the GenAI initiatives many of these employees have had deep, proven, and marked effects on the community.

It's not just sucky - the company might have once again traded the present and future of our communities for a much more uncertain future.

As a long time user of the network - I have literally seen the same cycles of chasing a product at the expense of the public sites and seeing it fail.

I was excited to see actual concrete good for the community from CM hires and such. The current direction seems to have rolled back the good work of the past few years.

It's easy to see a silver lining when you haven't been rained on. And frankly when your house hasn't been partially dismantled for a distant Lord's castle.

The long term picture isn't rosy, and should overflow AI fail, trust you couldn't afford to spend is burnt

It isn't any different from ... Many previous times. It was careers not AI but we got the same promises of better days we never saw.

The practical effects are very much loss, sorrow and frankly a loss in confidence

Comment: Thank you for your frank thoughts. I've always valued that when we talk, truly.  I struggle a little here because, given the exposure that I have to different sets of people (end users, customers) I think the future is brighter than you portray.  But the dystopian landscape that you're painting is certainly one that keeps me up at night.  That's what I want to work to prevent.  In other words, I hear your concern, and I'm watching for it.  So are others. I don't have magic words to assure you that it won't go that way, but I will do everything in my power to ensure that it doesn't.

Comment: @Philippe From our vantage point, things look bleak. Really bleak. This dystopian view is not just a view, it's how we are living this relationship with SO. And this is very real, it's not simply a fleeting moment. The company has stated so many times that the Community is important, yet the actions taken tend to prove the exact opposite. At least on our end of the monologue (I dare not call it a conversation). We lost V2Blast and Cat in this round, but we also lost many others in the very recent history (Shog, Jon, Robert, and others I certainly have forgotten). (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) The management will eventually have to realize that _saying_ that that Community is important and _acting_ accordingly do not represent the same amount of effort. The Community has tried time and again to communicate what it needs to thrive, yet it is being ignored while questionable features are being pushed as being "for the good of the Community". We have understood a while ago now that decisions are being made for the good of the Company, and not the Community.

Comment: @Philippe I've seen storm clouds for over a decade, and kept up hope for what now feels like the *merest* rays of sum peeking through. There's no preventing dystopia - its where we have now. Trust is again broken, people who we *need* out of the company, and a focus on things we don't actually care about.  I've heard too many 'next time it'll be better' or 'Its just temporary' or worse, justifications for decision that hurt the community . To borrow a line from Taylor Swift... I've seen this film before and I didn't like the ending.  And I don't see it anything that changes it

Comment: With so many of these exercises we lose core members of the community in the company with no true replacements, with promises that its the last time.  And frankly as much as the company wants a clean slate, we remember and we see the *exact same things* over and over again.  The only difference is the room for redemption, for reconciliation,  and healing gets smaller every time.

Comment: "*It's easy to see a silver lining when [... frankly ...] your house hasn't been partially dismantled for a distant Lord's castle*" Very well said. I'm feeling for those who were laid off especially.

Comment: @Philippe Forgive me, but I keep seeing comments that brush of the "dystopian" scenario described by users as either over pessimism or something that we didn't reach yet and you are working to prevent. Forgetting for a second how much I disagree  on both points, can I take this opportunity to ask if you (as in: the company) have ever asked yourself WHY the community would dream these dystopian realities? I mean, unless this turned overnight into "Emo Exchange" we can't all be a bunch of negative pessimist, right? There must be something that make us say that thing are bleak...

Comment: @SPArcheon, It's my job to pay attention to the dystopian outlook (and every other outlook that I see on site) and sort through them and raise them to my boss, Prashanth.  In order to do that, yes, I have to consider and analyze the origins of those feelings, and I often make use of my team in so doing.  I don't mean to minimize or brush off those feelings, and that's not what happens.  I just also don't happen to totally agree with them.  From my seat, I see things differently.  Maybe that's access to data, or planning, or whatever, but I certainly don't discount the community impressions.

Comment: @Philippe Then can I ask if the company could consider sharing these insight? I think that those analysis should clearly show that the userbase is felling neglected and not listened to. The company presence among us mortals is fading with every new cut. People like shog9 or Catija were key elements on meta, ones that would often interact in the chat and therefore people that the users seek out to make their voices heard. Even if it did nothing in the end, knowing that you told some of them about a problem gave you a felling of being listened that you are killing with these actions. [cont]

Comment: @Philippe [cont] I think you may also realize that despite those claims being very old, an userbase that sees its few trusted voices in the company silenced one after another is an userbase that will indeed remember the horrible words "only a 0,0001% vocal part of the actual users". I am probably repeating myself, but know that whatever may be the analysis you are doing internally, what users see externally is a company that clams up. And it does not help that many also see the objectives of Prosus as the current "man behind the curtain" being different from the objectives the old network had.

Comment: @SPArcheon - Reasonable question, and a good suggestion.  I'll sit with the relevant folks and see if there are any metrics that we're treating as non-public that we could consider exposing.

Comment: @SPArcheon month later, I'm sure you're very surprised your request has been ignored.

Answer (score 159):

Classical [roadmap towards a sale](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408451/1026459). Make big promises, cut back costs, pocket reserve cash, boast net revenue, sell.

My question is: who are some prospective buyers, and what is the projected sale's timing?

Comment: This question deals with topics outside of the one immediately at hand, and they are areas with which I have no personal involvement or knowledge. And even if I did, I think it would unreasonable to expect me to speculate as to prospective actions by another company.

Comment: Thank you for the response @Philippe, but of the spokespeople listed I didn't expect that this would be a topic you would address when I asked it. This is more of a question for Prashanth, however, I am aware he essentially does not post here. As for the topics at hand, the issue of sales positioning has been the driving force of this company for the past 2 years, and to be quite frank, the community is getting a little exhausted from it being so invasive to such topics.

Comment: I'll be sure that Prashanth sees the question then. :)

Comment: @Philippe Seconded as to the importance and relevance of this question. My current perception is that the *highest level* decisions at SO are being driven by goals and motivations which are rooted in greed/short-term exploitation, and not in the community's interest. I also have serious doubts as to the ability of top decision-makers to even *understand* the company's value, much less possessing of the imagination required to grow that value without destroying the thing itself. At the very least, it is relevant to demand some honesty about the *reasons* for the "financial targets" here.

Comment: When I think back to what SO was when created by Joel and look at what it has become today, it makes me sad. @BryKKan you've nailed it about their lack of ability to even understand what this place is. Heck, it has become the thing it set out to destroy.

Comment: Related: From *"[The people who make your apps go to Stack Overflow for answers. Here’s how it works](https://www.theverge.com/23421320/stack-overflow-ceo-interview-prashanth-chandrasekar-software-engineering-microsoft)"* (*[The Verge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Verge)*, 2022-10-25): *"We can still go public as a company if we want to, or we can continue to stay private if we want to."*. Though the interviewer keeps using the word "forum".

Answer (score 151):

You state:

> At the end, if you squint, I hope you’ll see the faint glimmer of a silver lining.

I've been squinting really hard, but maybe you could help me out and tell what to look for. Where should I look? Since I'm not seeing the silver lining of dismissing 2 veteran CMs while you consider "priorities may shift towards reliability and maintenance". Those CMs were pretty important for the reliability and maintenance, both short- and long-term.

Comment: Let's be real: Monday was not an easy day and quite honestly, that sentence referred to a section of the document that got cut, and I failed to remove that line.  The end result was that it seemed that I was was suggesting that the loss of our team members that were affected was a silver lining. That couldn't be farther from the truth, and I regret the editing error.  Instead, what I was hoping to portray, and missed the mark by a fairly large mark, was that as devastating as this news was there is a path forward and we are commited to walking it with you.

Comment: That "silver lining" is all the "silver" they get to keep from not having pay these people anymore. (as others have said, *many* have hired far more people than they can sustain paying. and SE isn't exactly a paid-for service.) [I've been there. It's never fun when it's your paycheck no one wants to write anymore.]

Answer (score 134):

When the moderation strike ended earlier this year, the [outcome of the negotiations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391847/moderation-strike-results-of-negotiations) was posted. I'm concerned about how the company is going to keep up its end of the agreement here.

First and foremost:

> Improving day-to-day communication between staff and moderators

How will this be accomplished? The Community team has lost two highly respected members of the team. They were also two of the most visible members of the team.

Where is the community manager->community relationship at this point? I'm saying that it is much closer to the "Non-existent" end of the spectrum than "Fully engaged two way communication" end.

---

> Tooling for mod communication and determining if the company violated the Mod Agreement

Combining one statement

> Longer-term projects that are more piecemeal in nature, such as time spent servicing requests for new tools, may also be impacted and responsiveness may slow down. My commitments during the recent moderator action negotiations remain intact, and we will continue to honor them.

with another

> It’s important to us that the sites continue to function as designed. Like I said, the community isn’t going anywhere. That means we’ll still prioritize bug-fixes as usual, and maintain our uptime. Any reduction in our work throughput will come from other areas of product development.

I don't know how to reconcile these two. How are you going to honor your commitments while also reducing the relationships that were *vital* in getting even minimal tooling upgrades out the door? At the same time you are pushing the generative AI brouhaha even in this announcement. It's clear that remains a priority. How do the other commitments the company made to the community fit into this new landscape with fewer employees and fewer Company->Community relationships?

Comment: There's no question that losing those two is hard.  I miss them personally and professionally.  But I still have some long-term very dedicated community managers who will step up.  In previous times, they may have been assigned to less public tasks, but that doesn't mean they aren't capable of doing the type of public work that these two were so good at - it just means that they were assigned to work in other areas.  Work assignments are going to have to change, clearly.

Comment: @Philippe I don't think it's about the capability of the *remaining* community managers, but rather the rapport that the ones we've lost had with the community. That's not something that is fixed by reassigning tasks, it's a relationship of trust built over time. Those personal relationships had survived breakdowns in the broader relationship between company and curators and seemed like the most promising avenues for mending the broader relationship.

Comment: That task has also been an extremely burdensome one as far as I can tell, and I fear the extreme pressure this is going to put on your remaining staff who seem even less comfortable with that role than the CMs affected by the layoff.

Comment: @BryanKrause - it's not the easiest job in the world, nor is it the hardest. But each and every person on my team knows that they will be called upon to do it. You dont' get into community management without being willing to engage with communities.  I appreciate your thoughts for them, but I think they'll be fine.  Let's give them a chance to prove it.

Comment: @Philippe I understand the reason for your "political answers", good and bad. I understand you have a job to do, and that to some extent it's required. However, it's not like I don't notice when you're sidestepping and reframing issues in an attempt to "non-answer" the hard questions. It's frustrating to watch you continually move around the fact that *the community* isn't "fine" here.

Comment: @Philippe I am not suggesting the remaining team is *unwilling* to engage, please do not insult me or them by putting those words in my mouth.

Answer (score 131):

Regardless of the nuances of the full picture, and as stated by Prashanth in his blog post, this layoff is part of the company's path to profitability--profit has 2 elements--income and cost. Layoffs reduce "cost" (in the form of humans and salary).

Based off LinkedIn, social media, this post, and conversations with friends, with a few notable exceptions, the layoff has affected the lives of many individual contributors from across the company, and only a select few managers.

I would appreciate answers to these three discrete questions, which all get to the main question of "Have senior leadership (VP+) shouldered any of the financial burden currently facing 120-something employees?"

- Will senior leadership forego bonuses and raises this year?
- Has senior leadership taken a reduction in pay so that they can share in the salary cost-cutting?
- Or are individual contributors expected to fully shoulder the direct financial impact of the company's strategy which resulted in the layoffs?

---

#### Why do I care? Why should users care?

Stack Overflow became what it is today because it was able to attract top-tier talent across all areas, both as employees and as volunteer content creators on the site. Top talent is choosy about where they work, and will choose to work where they feel respected and working on things they love. I hope that the company treated all laid off employees with the respect and compassion they deserve, and this is one important measure of that.

Comment: This is the question. If "community" is so important to them, what % pay cut did the C-suite decline to take, that would have saved the CM jobs? I'd be willing to bet it's in the very low single digits.

Comment: SO is two years+ into a a buyout, the countdown is on to the investors flipping the company get their money out. Layoffs are the easy route to dress up the financials to get someone else to buy out the original investors. That is the long and short of what passes for a strategy.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver --- That is certainly one possibility. I'm not here to speculate as to whether Prosus is seeking to sell Stack Overflow or not. My question is meant to distill whether the company is treating its employees (my former coworkers) with the compassion and respect they deserve....

Comment: [Due to cutbacks, we're gonna have to fire Dave](https://9gag.com/gag/av5MRKE)

Comment: @EricDuminil  - that's clever.  Thanks for the saturday morning chuckle.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Does nobody care about the fact that clumsy layoffs **often** eliminate crucial knowledge, skills, and *relationships* which the company relies upon to support those underlying numbers?

Comment: @BryKKan - I've yet to see layoffs that don't do this, clumsy or otherwise.

Comment: @Philippe -- This is the highest voted question (+106 / -0) without a response. From my perspective, it seems like a relatively objective answer which should be fairly easy. The silence seems like a deafening response in and of itself. I can only assume that a response may be unflattering/undesirable to answer. I'm profoundly disappointed. 

Comment: Your questions are probably backwards. Senior leadership will get bonuses and raises this year, because they supposedly increased short term profitability™ thanks to the layoffs.

Comment: @EricDuminil It’s well deserved, after those tough decisions.

Answer (score 107):

What will become of the development projects that Catija and other devs were involved in? There were some initiatives (such as mod tooling) she was acting as liaison on in the SO mod room.

Comment: The question generally says that ongoing projects might be delayed or changed. Maybe more detailed fates haven't yet been decided but it's clear that with less work force less projects can be done at the same time.

Comment: Every team in the company, including Product and Engineering, was impacted. Mod Tooling and other community facing projects that were being worked on are still a priority. There is a slight pause right now as teams regroup and reassign any roles and responsibilities that need coverage. We'll be sharing more details once they are ironed out and letting you know next steps on these inisatives and who on the Community Management team will be point people on those projects.

Comment: @Philippe for posterity, if you do that as a new question post, please also link to it here in a comment. thanks!

Answer (score 97):

> Projects undergoing active work may change scope or be canceled.

Does that also hold for your GenAI initiatives? Will you continue to invest as much resources and energy into GenAI initiatives as before?

It seems to be a fact that your projects will suffer from this layoff. But it will be significantly worse if you are not willing to reduce the amount of energy/men(and women)power/money you put into GenAI.

Please consider reducing the focus on GenAI and ensure everything else doesn't fall apart completely.

---

(personal opinion/very biased)

If you don't, I only see the situation becoming even worse for SE (and the Community but the Community doesn't seem to be important for SE judging from what SE is doing (I am talking about SE as a company here, I am sure CMs are still caring about the Community, even without Catja and V2Blast)) in the future. And with "the situatuation becoming even worse for SE", I fear that 2 layoffs from now, even the CEO might be impacted.

Please, for the sake of god/allah/buddah/business or whatever you believe in: Don't take (any more) bets (on GenAI) you can't afford to lose (because you seem to be losing them).

Comment: Although I agree, the CEO perspective on this is that StackOverflow has to be building *something* new oriented toward growing revenue.  We, the users of SO, recognize that GenAI is a bad idea for SO.  But the sales team needs buzzwords to market the Teams product.  Sadly, we can't just say "kill GenAI"--we have to offer a more compelling alternative way for SO to drive revenue.

Comment: Yes and I didn't request to completely "kill GenAI" (just to put less resources/effort into it and focus on what's important). However, I don't think it would work out if they kept the same focus on it.

Comment: And it would be a relief (and I think a lot of people here would agree on that) to hear that no big GenAI initiatives were planned - but that might just be wishful thinking.

Comment: Honestly, if Stack Overflow wanted to make a competitive GenAI product, they'd need to increase spending on it, massively. There's no use in having a worse conversational AI than Copilot/ChatGPT/CodeWhisperer/Replit etc. Microsoft has recently realized how enormously tricky integrating hallucinating GenAI in a business product is, so I don't see it being sensible for Teams either. Just investing a bit serves no other purpose than having something to talk about to investors. And given that GenAI has been a huge money burning machine for nearly all companies, that's not that useful either.

Comment: Well, I don't think they can afford doing that.

Comment: Indeed, so they should scrap it fully. There's no in-between with AI

Comment: Not sure how realistic that is but I don't feel I am in the position to request that.

Comment: @ErikA There's no in-between with AI systems _intended to be generalist_ – a big part of OpenAI's brand is producing “AGI” (which is awful at most stuff, but it _attempts_ most stuff! Wow!). Special-purpose AI, like auto-summarisation tools for specific fields, can require vastly fewer resources while producing better outcomes: we had decent auto-summarisation tools before “LLM” was coined, we had decent OCR and image recognition of pastries before massive neural networks became a thing, etc..

Comment: Also if one uses an LLM for tasks special-purpose AI systems could be good for, they shouldn't expect too much of it.

Comment: Since AFAIK there's not been a single company so far that's made a profit from genAI, I'd say it's insane that they don't just cut that tumor off from the company, instead of firing quite literally essential and priceless employees like V2Blast.

Comment: Glad someone brought up this elephant. The whole point of the SE network (all sites) has been the human interaction and knowledge. Replacing people with computers that "think" can only go poorly. Whether here or at any company/site.

Answer (score 87):

At the time of writing this answer, on SO's main page, the featured blog post is "Is AI enough to increase your productivity?".

[image: Original screen capture]

This... doesn't look good, given the circumstances. This whole AI thing is already infuriating as it is, and now that many people lost their job, it adds a taste of arrogance which we could do without.

Is there any way you guys can just remove this link for now?

### Edit

Good news, the link to the article was removed. Less good news, we can still see an article on LLMs O_o

[image: New screen capture]

@Philippe: The Community does not agree with the AI initiatives being pushed by the Company. That was made abundantly clear in various posts on Meta.SE and other sites. This is a pain point for us and this is creating a rift between the Company and the Community.

You said that the Company cares about its Community. If this is indeed the case, please consider putting a hold on the AI-related articles being pushed? This would be a very clear display of how much you truly care about the Community. Then maybe you can find a way to exchange with the Community about their views on possible AI-related initiatives that could be helpful in our opinion?

Comment: At the layoffs in May the blog featured an article on finding a job ....  Maybe the blog authors are on our side and send us messages early for things to come. Look out for *How to go bankrupt* or *Survive a hostile takeover* ...

Comment: @rene Why not wish for something hopeful? E.g. "How to bring a new CEO up to speed in record time!"

Answer (score 81):

I have a question for Mr. Prashanth Chandrasekar.

A while ago, [Joel Spolsky made a post announcing your arrival at Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/24/announcing-stack-overflows-new-ceo-prashanth-chandrasekar/)

At the time, one of the things that was said was the following:

> Last March, I shared that we were starting to look for a new CEO for Stack Overflow. We were looking for that rare combination of someone who could foster the community while accelerating the growth of our businesses, especially Teams, where we are starting to close many huge deals and becoming a hyper-growth enterprise software company very quickly. This is not something I’m particularly good at, and I thought it was time to bring on more experienced leadership.

By them, it seemed Stack Overflow was going *really well.* Joel there talks about lots of opportunities arriving, and needing more experienced leadership to help managing things going forward.

A few years later, [came the huge acquisition by Prosus](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/06/02/prosus-acquires-stack-overflow/).

With that acquisition, you personally mentioned that:

> Once this acquisition is complete, we will have more resources and
> support to grow our public platform and paid products, and we can
> accelerate our global impact tremendously. This might look like more
> rapid and robust international expansion, M&A opportunities, and
> deeper partnerships both on Stack Overflow and within Stack Overflow
> for Teams.

And that:

> Prosus is a long-term investor and loves what our company and
> community have built over these last 13+ years. They are impressed by
> the SaaS transformation the company has been on since the launch of
> Stack Overflow for Teams and especially over the last two years.
> Prosus recognizes our platform’s tremendous potential for impact and
> they are excited to launch and accelerate our next phase of growth.

Very promising words! Acquisitions are scary, but those were words that promised greatness to come and that things would only get better. That happened around the middle of 2021.

Fast forward just two years later, to 2023, and now we find ourselves on a strange situation where a third of the workforce, including people that were highly valued by the community, had to be let go in order to recover profitability.

A third of the workforce.

A third of the workforce being let go after very good news a few years ago is not a minor reorganization or a strategic shift. It's something very major, that doesn't happen from one moment to another. It feels like things are going very, very bad, and we as a community don't understand what is going on. I think I speak for many of us when I say that we're in the dark of *why* this was necessary.

We don't understand how things came to this. We had the acquisition, the big deals, the promises of growth and getting better and better, and now a third of the people that work on the company lost their jobs.

How did the situation got this dire?

Comment: They weren't talking to us. They were talking to investors. Cutting employees by a third with a heavy focus on the sales oriented teams makes sense if you need that money to develop technology instead of growing the community or customer base. This should not be a surprise to anyone who listened to what the CEO was saying about AI. They believe that any erosion in the community this causes is either going to be slow enough to be reversed later, or completely irrelevant to the company's future.

Comment: Some meta post within the past few days claimed (the reference escapes me right now) they grew 100% within a short time. +100% - 10% - 30% = +25% (they aren't additive).

Comment: "How did the situation got this dire?" It's not a full explanation, but sure not many people predicted the rise of Language Models so quickly back then and the issues with quality, curation and user experience and a decline in participation on StackOverflow for example are long (many years) in the making. Also, Joel Spolski might have greatly exaggerated the "hyper growth" part. I'd say that the situation never was that rosy, but it still got worse and worse over the years.

Comment: Not sure I read this answer correctly - are you suggesting that CEO communications are anything else than hot air? Also, as mentioned above, SO doubled its workforce last year and thus the headcound is actually still higher than 2021. As for "how things came to this", that's what happens when a CEO does not understand the core business of the company and instead chooses to chase the latest hype such as genAI, but still has financial targets to hit and thus needs to cut corners elsewhere...

Comment: Yeesh.  Thanks for digging up the Spolsky quote in particular.  Looks like he would have done better to stay as CEO himself in spite of his "not particularly good at" disclaimer.  Is he still chairman, do you know?

Comment: @l4mpi Mr. Prashanth Chandrasekar was brought in as someone that had the necessary expertise to move towards a good future, and his own statements made clear that growth was assured. Now the company faces a major retraction. Something is amiss - or we are lacking important context, or this was a major fumble under his responsibility. This is the moment to either explain, or accept blame. Sustainable hiring is a concept that should be on any modern CEO handbook.

Comment: SO doubled its workforce within a single year? That sounds like it was overly rushed maybe.

Comment: @T.Sar you seem to have an overinflated view of CEOs and an uncritical acceptance of company communications. Your source for the claim about the current CEO is a blog post by the previous CEO, which is biased and will try to give as rosy a view as possible (e.g. hypothetically, if Joel was forced out by activist investors, you won't read about that in the blog). Maybe he actualy was brought in to prepare for acquisition. Re CEO handbook, FAANG went on a similar hiring spree during the pandemic and also found out this is not sustainable; and tech CEOs often seem to chase / imitate FAANG.

Comment: @l4mpi Please don't assume things about me. I'm bringing up those blog posts as-is because they're explicitly what Stack Exchange _said_. They are their own company communication. It's their word against themselves. What I truly think about this situation is far too unkind for a place of polite discussion.

Comment: @T.Sar "What I truly think about this situation is far too unkind for a place of polite discussion" - then I think we're pretty much on the same page. I'm just saying the blog is a place for fluff pieces... it could state that Prashanth will strive to gift every single SO user a unicorn in real life and I would take that just as serious as I took the "becoming a hyper-growth enterprise software company very quickly" line (how much that sentence aligned with reality should be obvious given that they've now fired most of their marketing for SO Teams).

Comment: OK, it wasn't a meta post (but it was linked from one (or a comment on one)): [The 2023-10-16](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2023/10/after-chatgpt-disruption-stack-overflow-lays-off-28-percent-of-staff/) [Ars Technica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ars_Technica) article, citing [a 2022-10-25](https://www.theverge.com/23421320/stack-overflow-ceo-interview-prashanth-chandrasekar-software-engineering-microsoft) [The Verge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Verge) article: ***"Stack Overflow doubled its headcount in 2022 with 525 people"***

Comment: Rich people at the top of things want to get even more richer. That's the answer.

Answer (score 76):

One of the impacted CMs was the last remaining person who would straddle between the difficulties of communicating to the community and representing the company. Some of their announcements and projects were generally well received, and it was the impression that for as long as they were around, things could at least start to heal.

With their departure and with the calamities that have already befallen this community, what words could you offer to someone like me who would use this chance to forever give up any faith that the company is on the right track and that the community is being taken care of?

Comment: The company hasn't been on the 'right' track for many years,  as evidenced by the boom and bust cycles as they chase the next shiny thing.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Yes, that's well established. But like any bad relationship there's some irrational thing that causes you to cling onto hope, and one of those CMs was that. With her gone, it all feels hollow now.

Comment: Everyone impacted whether on the CM or any other team is a great loss. I do want to point out though that every member of the CM team does as @makoto says "straddle between the difficulties of communicating to the community and representing the company." Everyone on this team advocates for the Community both internally and externally. For over a year now Community Managers have been formally liaisioning with teams across Product, Engineering, Design, etc...

Comment: ....They serve as your voice in planning meetings and work with Product Managers to syntheize your feedback, respond to it, and push for changes that will benefit you. But going foward, we need to do a better job of sharing more about our liaision work and what that intails - and that's on me. Teams are regrouping right now and figuring out coverage but Rosie is planning to share more details with you about liaision work in the upcoming weeks.

Comment: @Philippe:  I do not *trust* that anyone on the team advocates for the actual long-term members of the site. It has not been demonstrated in a measurable way that our voice is really being heard or that our concerns are being addressed or that our feedback *counts*.  While I know that Catija couldn't *promise* anything, if nothing else she was pretty no nonsense about it, and owned up where things fell short.  Everyone else has been utterly transparent and largely in the background to this point and has not owned up when they let us down.

Comment: @Philippe:  The struggle that is shown here with CMs is that they're just *not* visible to us anymore.  We don't feel their presence when interacting with us and it takes *years* to build a rapport in this fashion.  I categorically reject this papering over what has been lost with "well, everyone in the room is championing for the community".  No, it has not felt like that.  It has not felt like that in a very, very long time.

Comment: @Makoto Some remaining CMs have a similar rapport with some moderators… but it's going to be a few years before anyone's rapport with the wider community reaches Catija's. (I don't even know if the conditions for developing a rapport like that still exist.)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I feel like CMs have to also be regular users on their accounts on at least one site (but preferably multiple) for them to build any sort of ongoing presence with the wider community - Catija and V2Blast had that in spades. Kinda hard to do if you're coming into Stack without any prior interaction though :/

Comment: If only there were sites that aligned with the new CMs' hobbies, it's not like we have over a 100 of them...

Comment: @wizzwizz4: Well, that's good for the moderators then. Maybe one day us non-mods might be able to share in that privilege.

Answer (score 75):

> today’s actions will allow us to be more strategic and to narrow our focus as we move forward.

This statement implies that the individuals whose jobs were eliminated-- who are largely individual contributors executing on strategy set by senior leadership-- were somehow responsible for a lack of strategic focus.

That's a terrible thing to imply, and as a former employee I understand it is far from the truth. This phrase should be edited and frankly y'all should apologize for the insinuation.

I understand you are trying to find something positive to write, but throwing shade at the people whose jobs have been eliminated for somehow inhibiting strategy is a desperate look, not a community focused one or even a strategic one.

Comment: Yeah, the phrasing's not great. I imagine it's difficult to find a way to say "layoffs will help us accomplish our [financial] goals", but... I feel like this could have been phrased better.

Comment: @V2Blast I agree.  They could just come out and say "layoffs will help us accomplish our financial goals," but it's bad form to say what you mean anymore.

Comment: If that's the implication that came out of this sentence, it was certainly not intentional, and I do apologize for it.  I thought that the intention of the sentence was clear: it's incumbent on those who remain here, who are in management, to do a better job of focusing their work. No shade was intended, at all.

Answer (score 71):

> Practical effects of the October 2023 layoff

A CM who cares deeply about improving user onboarding and guidance is now no longer a voice inside the company. If anything, *that's* the kind of thing that I think will lead to anything like a "demise of Stack Overflow".

People don't hate SO because it needs more AI. (and I can give you [a long list of people who have found SO more helpful than ChatGPT](https://web.archive.org/web/20231018002910/https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1761361)). They hate it because the onboarding and guidance sucks, and then they kick their pinky toe on a disgruntled curator who is equally frustrated at the situation.

I just want to scream- "WHY!?".

My disappointment is immeasurable and my day is ruined.

Comment: We share your deep disappointment and frustration. We really valued all of our teammates that were laid off, on our team and beyond, and we will miss working with them greatly. We hope to honor the contributions of those that are no longer here by remaining commmitted to improving the experience of both new and seasoned users on the public platform. Although these staff members were consistent voices for the topics you mention - onboarding, etc, they were not by any means the ONLY consistent voices for prioritizing those things.

Comment: Unfortunately, the hate SO gets may not be fixable with onboarding and guidance.  It's a perception problem of what the site does by outsiders.  They see SO as coding forum or chat room to ask questions, rather than a place already full of answers they can use.  I had a friend who is reasonably intelligent, but she said to me that she sees no harm in asking a question on SO without searching first.  She said, "It doesn't matter if I waste a little bit of somebody's time because I didn't search.  It's just one question."  That perception is the problem, and it exists outside of SO's control.

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler that kind of misunderstanding is part of what I'm talking about when I talk about bad onboarding and guidance: understanding the platform's goal and chosen path to achieve that goal.

Comment: @starball I understood your stated goal and was addressing it in my comment. It's ambitious to believe one can redirect users who already have a mistaken vision of the purpose of the site.  You can't add more text and get different behavior than they planned; you have to constrain courses of action or change expectations of the world at large.  I don't think SO has the advertising budget for the latter nor the will to remove the ability of new users to ask questions without searching first, especially when one of the current CEO's first KPIs was to increase total number of questions.

Comment: @Conspicuous Compiler: They could redesign the looks and the way it works, so it doesn't *look* like a forum. Even force new users to jump through some hoops to make it clear [it isn't a forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stackexchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum/36828#36828). Even [the CEO thinks it is a forum](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPbbt7Dg-2U&t=2m57s).

Answer (score 69):

The last announcement about the earlier layoffs said

> This is painful for them, and we are supporting those employees through this transition with severance packages, extensions of healthcare benefits, and outplacement services.

There is no such statement in the current announcement. Is there anything the company leadership wants to add about this aspect of the layoffs?

Comment: The WARN Act requires a 60-day notice for employers over 100 employees (which includes Stack Overflow) so I'm sure they are continuing to pay their salaries and benefits for the next two months. That is usually what companies refer to when they say things like 'we will continue to support these employees for the near future as they find new work'.

Comment: @TylerH Only if the layoff is large enough to qualify. I don't know whether the previous layoff would combine with this one to make it qualify since it wasn't too long ago. Another complication is that not all of the employees are in the US.

Comment: @BryanKrause You're right; now it looks like Stack Overflow planned to lay off this 28% all along but spaced it out 6 months from the last 10% layoff to avoid the 33% threshold. Great optics!

Comment: @MadScientist, everyone impacted today was provided with a severance package with some variation depending on geographical location and tenure.

Comment: I understand that the severance compensation from this round is significantly less than what was offered during the prior round in May.

Comment: They didn't even have the decency to warn or even tell these folks privately that they are being fired. At least one former CM simply woke up and couldn't access their stuff and that's how they learned they had been laid off. Seriously. They didn't even have the decency to tell them face to face or at least directly.

Comment: @terdon  Funny, this is how contractors are treated, not employees

Comment: _"At least one former CM simply woke up and couldn't access their stuff"_ Casualty of timezones? With a global workforce, there's probably some SOP for that, but I imagine it's tricky.

Comment: @terdon- We attempted to meet with every team member face to face.  The worst scenario is for someone to wake up and not have access.  To that end, we sent an announcement at 7AM eastern to staff so that they could see it on waking up. We then started by notifying Europe and moving west.  The two CMs that were impacted were around the 11:00 hour (Eastern).  I will not speak to the particular circumstances of anyone, but know that in every case, we tried multiple methods to contact the affected employees before their access was removed.

Comment: @Philippe I've only ever seen “we tried multiple methods to contact [blank]” said to me or others when the communication strategy was woefully and fundamentally inadequate (the failures disproportionately, though not exclusively, affecting neurodivergent or disabled individuals; in at least one case systematically). I don't know if this is such a case, but I'd recommend improving your approach for next time (which would likely include giving more notice than one working day – ideally a proper notice period) and informing the remaining employees of those policy improvements.

Comment: @Philippe You don't "notify" layoffs. You notify _the beginning of a discussion about_ layoffs, so that _eventually_, _at the end of the process_, _if no alternative was found_, the affected workers at least don't get any completely unexpected surprise. This is basic workplace decency.

Comment: Wow that's mad, in the UK and Europe you would not get away with that!

Answer (score 67):

I wanted to post this message yesterday, but then decided against it to avoid further drama. Then I saw Zoe’s answer and the company comment on that, asking almost what I wanted to ask.

> Then why, over the past two firings (and previous rounds), have you eliminated the CMs and other employees who were among the largest advocates for the community and who, in some of the worse periods, were the only communication channel with the company? (**Zoe post**)

> Not just the CMs. And in fact, this time around the CM team was hit much lighter than many other teams, because of the critical role that it plays here. But ultimately, decisions needed to be made to reach a certain target, and there was no way to protect the CM team entirely. Nobody has more respect for the CM team than I do. I'm feeling the cuts very personally today. I was blessed to work with them, and once they're on my team, that's forever, and I will celebrate every time I see them. (**company comment**)

> @Philippe You're missing the point (and the "CMs and other employees" bit). The point is that over the past few years, the company has fired many of the outward-facing staff members who actually believed in, and advocated for the community. With this last round of employees being fired, the list of remaining community advocates (that, more importantly, also has the faith of the community) has shrunk.
> (**Zoe answer**)

I can't even begin to say how annoyed I was by this exchange and how the company comment seem to completely miss the point Zoe was making.

I think it is very obvious even from the outside that right now that the company is internally divided in two factions:

- one that sees the community as an issue/hindrance and something that must be controlled, avoided, corrected, cleaned.
- one that recognizes the community as the core of the network value and the central focus of what need to be done to move forward. Those seek collaboration and reconciliation instead of control.

Many users currently seems to share the feeling that the "cut offs" are surgically aimed at removing the second faction, the one that historically has shown support to the community in order to allow the other to progress in their plan more easily.

The comment on Zoe's answer avoided this issue completely. I am therefore posting this more direct question in hope to get some insight on that. Some attempts to tell us why this is just pessimistic thinking. Something that should make us change our wrong interpretation and be more trustful.

I'll leave you with this "artistic interpretation" of what is happening that I saw many users rant about in the last few months. Mind you, it is just a half-parody that hopefully isn't true at all, but I am posting it in hope this pushes some triggers and causes an epiphany to what a growing part of the community is thinking about the company right now.

> Prosus bought the Stack Exchange network with the only purpose to use its data to train its proprietary LLM. For this reason they are pushing everything in the AI direction, researching more ways to use the available data to develop other products. At the same time they are trying to find way to ensure the exclusivity of their "market advantage", for example by trying to render competitors unable to use the same data (see: data dump, how can we kill the Creative Commons).
> The network is seen as a cost to pay to obtain more data. The focus is therefore to reduce that cost at much as possible while still obtaining that data, not to further develop the community. Depending on how things progress, the network will be kept open and slowly converted to an advertisement for the core product (integrating Prosus LLM in the site to showcase its abilities) or shut down as soon at it won't produce any more useful data.

Again, this is just an "Evil Incorporated Inc." comic-book style made-up story that in no way has to be true (nor in any way I am claiming it is). Yet, the sole fact that many users would consider this bleak scenario even ***plausible*** should really ring some big alarm bells in your heads.

Comment: To anyone at the company who is listening: As an exercise, can you come up with any externally visible actions (not words) of senior leadership since the acquisition, that are not consistent with this artistic interpretation? That is what breaks trust and encorages these narratives.

Comment: @user1937198 as I said, I don't have any pretense to be able to tell apart what the truth actually is behind all the mess that happened in these years. Yet I think it would still be useful for the company to reflect about **WHY** so many users now see them as one of those mustached villain from some old western movie, wearing their top hat as they tie the network to the train tracks.

Comment: Here's what Joel had to say about Prosus in the first place—all of which is consistent with your Evil, Inc. scenario: *Prosus is a long-term investor and loves what our company and community have built over these last 13+ years. They are impressed by the SaaS transformation the company has been on since the launch of Stack Overflow for Teams and especially over the last two years. Prosus recognizes our platform’s tremendous potential for impact and they are excited to launch and accelerate our next phase of growth.*

Answer (score 64):

Some further thoughts -

I would refer you to this [verge article](https://www.theverge.com/2023/10/16/23919004/stack-overflow-layoff-ai-profitability)

> After the team doubled its employee base last year, Chandrasekar told The Verge’s Nilay Patel in an interview that about 45 percent of those hires were for its go-to-market sales team, which he said was “obviously the largest team.” We’ve reached out to Stack Overflow to find out what other teams may have been affected.

This has generally been a cycle. SE's *best* years were as a community and engineering centric company with a product that was best in class.

Considering that this has been *identical* to the events that lead to ... every other downsizing, what does the company intend to do 'better'? While the consequences to the individual contributors who're downsized is clear, I feel like nothing has *actually* changed between CEOs with respect to this.

With a smaller sales team, and a core community that's beaten, bruised and exhausted, and a engineering and community team that's shed people - how *exactly* does

As per the [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/10/16/stack-overflow-company-announcement-october-2023/)

> continued product innovation of Stack Overflow for Teams and the health of the public platform by building out our AI/ML capabilities.

*Actually* benefit any of us and

> As we refine our focus, priorities, and strategy it's to better meet the demands of our users, customers, and partners as part of this commitment to product innovation and the continued momentum of OverflowAI both for Stack Overflow for Teams and on our public platform. Our new team structure best positions us to succeed when it comes to these initiatives.

As a core and *vocal* community member we have seen many requests be put on the back burner, or frankly ignored due to lack of resources. Multiple rounds of downsizing due to *non profitability* shows you're not meeting your financial goals, and loss of *core* community facing employees over time shows you've failed in your commitment to the community.

Considering the failure in meeting many of the needs of the community, down to a unprecedented protest action shortly before these downsizing events, one might consider the strategies so far a complete failure.

I asked about this in [May](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389558/stack-exchange-is-failing-its-community) - and apparently the response to "What are you going to do" seems to be to double down on actions that hurt the community.

What *does* success look like in the face of this?

I ask as I have before. I've seen concrete steps that have stripped away vital community resources and put back many projects again. What concrete steps, not promises (which feel worthless right now) does the company intend to take to serve the community and protect their interests?

We clearly see the impact of poor decision making by management on *staff*. I guess the question is how many cycles does the same "we're increasing our sales focus" "we're losing money" cycle have to happen before there's nothing left.

Answer (score 56):

My main issue is, among the roughly 28% of the workforce that has just been laid off, were there any at a management level? If so, then secondarily, assuming it's permitted to be publicly disclosed, what number and/or percentage of the total being laid off would that be? Finally, are the numbers of these managerial level lay offs in the various groups/departments, compared to those of regular workers, roughly similar, or are there some that are significantly more or less affected?

---

Note that [Philippe's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393806/practical-effects-of-the-october-2023-layoff/393822#comment1317124_393822) states

> Yes, management was impacted, up to and including at least one VP. ... But I think I can safely say that just as with the layoffs of individual contributors, management layoffs were clustered around the same solidly impacted teams, primarily Go-to-market focused.

Comment: I bet it is anywhere between 0% to 0%.

Comment: I'll also bet the reduction upper management took to their own bonus and salary is anywhere between 0% and any amount of increase  instead

Comment: Yes, management was impacted, up to and including at least one VP.  I'll see if I can get the numbers, but honestly I don't know if I'll be allowed to release those.  I'll ask.  But I think I can safely say that just as with the layoffs of individual contributors, management layoffs were clustered around the same solidly impacted teams, primarily Go-to-market focused.

Comment: @Philippe But you're a VP and you appear to be really quite low down in the company hierarchy. At least from what I've seen - it doesn't seem like you've been able to affect much meaningful change so far. If the company is in such a dire financial state I'd expect more executives to be moved on too.

Comment: I'm not sure that I agree with your reading of my role.  In terms of company hierarchy, I report to the CEO.  In terms of meaningful change, well, I grew the very team that we're talking about here, among other things. I wouldn't expect you to know about the change that I bring, though, because much of it is necessarily backstage.  But I'm proud of the liaison program that I introduced, for instance, and for our closer and tighter cross-functional relationships. :)

Comment: @Philippe Thank you for the info. I assume you're not permitted to provide the specific numbers. As indicated in my answer, I suspected this might happen because, in my admittedly very limited experience, companies try to limit how much internal company details are released publicly. However, as I've made it clearer in updated my answer, I was primarily concerned about there being any management who were affected. Although it's best nobody's laid off, there's a sense of "fairness" if it's not just lower-level people. Finally, note I've now included part of your comment in my answer.

Answer (score 52):

So, let's compare the Stack Exchange organisation with a wayward truck. This truck has a history of taking wrong turns and unnecessary diversions, which is causing it to consume far too much fuel and is costing its owner big money. How can we fix this?

First approach: Let's remove one of the rear axles/wheelsets. That will save money, for sure, and maybe that axle is the cause of the wrong turns.

Nope! That didn't work; the company is still losing money because of this wayward truck.

Second attempt: Let's knock out the headlights. Clearly, they are far too bright and dazzling, and are likely making it hard for the driver to read road signs. This is obviously contributing to the unnecessary diversions (and those lights also consume energy/fuel). So: Scrapping the headlights will save us money.

Nope! That didn't work either.

At what point will the truck's owners wake up and realize that the cause of the  wrong turns and diversions is … **the driver**?

Comment: Not yet. They’ll first open the doors, and throw out all the passengers, and then dump the goods the truck is carrying, in an attempt to make the last few liters of fuel be enough to get back on the road.

Comment: @AndreasismovingtoCodidact Actually, the driver grabs half the goods when they bail out before the tank hits empty if past corporate declines are any indication.

Comment: @ColleenV But the brakes will likely fail before the tank goes empty. Jumping out is the only reasonable thing to do. Taking the goods is only considered a fair exchange for the danger the driver was in.

Comment: don't forget to grab a big box of genAI to put on the hood so we can't see where we are going.

Answer (score 51):

> [ from Prashanth's blog [post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/10/16/stack-overflow-company-announcement-october-2023/) ]  *To our community members and customers reading this note: you are foundational to our success. Thank you for your continued partnership as we enter this next phase*.

My translation: *we fart in your general direction, but we'll be happy to milk your contributions while you still stick around and volunteer*. Calling it a "partnership" is between disingenuous and downright insulting at this point.

"Lost trust" has been mentioned several times in the previous posts, in the GenAI fiasco and strike discussions before this, in the Monica debacle years ago, and before that, too. Other than the goodwill of some SO staff, is there any reason to hope for the history *not* repeating itself next time around i.e. is SO management, and the CEO in particular, even aware of this "trust" issue, and do they have any concrete plans to repair/rebuild it?

Comment: Although I personally am quite familiar with it, and enjoyed your "translation", not everyone is knowledgeable about the "Monty Python and the Holy Grail" 1975 movie, e.g., the memorable quote #9 stated in [Best Quotes from Monty Python and the Holy Grail: 15 Funniest](https://www.pastemagazine.com/movies/monty-python/monty-python-and-the-holy-grail-best-quotes), i.e., "I don’t want to talk to you no more, you empty-headed animal food trough wiper. I fart in your general direction. Your mother was a hamster and your father smelt of elderberries." of the French knight to King Arthur.

Comment: [A clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QSo0duY7-9s&t=1m38s) (at 01 min 38 secs)

Comment: I've read the CEO's blog and given their inability to write anything coherent I seriously doubt their ability to understand what the problem is.

Comment: You know what, why are you all still here? If there truly isn't any trust left, there is nothing for you here. One might as well leave. Sure, the place won't survive without you, but in all seriousness, it won't even if you stay, because the company will run it into the ground. So seriously, if you don't trust the company at all, it's time to leave. Face the fact, and do something about it. It's time to leave this place behind.

Comment: (says the user who "moved to codidact" more than a month ago but is still more active here than there)

Comment: @KevinB No, yesterday I changed my username from "is moving to", to "moved to". I have ceased all post creations, and I'm no longer doing any curation tasks. I just happened to stumble upon this Q/A thread by random, because I'm still in some of the chat rooms, and never intended to leave them behind, because I still talk to people here. I'm leaving the platform, but not the community. Also, besides regular chat with people here (about stuff other than SE), I _am_ more active on Codidact now, than on SE. Even though it may not seem like that, I spend more time there than here)

Comment: @AndreasmovedtoCodidact Whatever you gotta tell yourself, ;)

Comment: @KevinB Although, I will be honest and say that I disputed the close reason for one question on MSE today.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, managing to tell myself what I needed to, was part of the moving process. I have had an addiction to this place. I like the people here. The community is nice (mostly). It doesn't happen in one day. And I'm not a particularly efficient person. So excuse my fatigue.

Answer (score 49):

I'm really struggling with

> Our commitment to the community remains unchanged.

and

> Community is among the most reliable cornerstones of the place – the
> essence of what makes this company what it is.

followed by

> Our responses to you will be temporarily disrupted.

and

> Short-term priorities may shift towards reliability and maintenance.

These things feel like opposites to me.

Consider this: Right now (4:38 pm Eastern on 16 October 2023), there are [211 [tag:status-review] questions on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-review?tab=Active). The kind of disruptions are going to seriously impact [the targets for addressing new posts as well as the backlog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393711/572).

The fact that two of the currently active CMs I can remember interacting with the most were laid off also strikes me as odd, especially considering [the agreements with the moderators and the community to improve day-to-day communication between staff and moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391847/572).

Phrased as a question: What are your concrete plans for achieving these commitments? Or, in the case of the quarterly targets, what's a new reasonable target?

Comment: If there are already 211 [status-review] questions here on Meta Stack Exchange, then the plan is simple, and it has already been in effect for a long time: Let the stack overflow, and the resulting `StackOverflowException` ([.NET architecture](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network)) is caught and ignored.

Comment: @rgettman That is not true. See the targets that have been set and the regular statusing. The number of status-review posts on Meta SE and across the network is a known issue and there were plans to try to address them.

Comment: @rgettman Follow (with notifications) this post for quarterly updates on how they're doing with status tagged posts and what their priorities are for the coming quarter: [What posts should be escalated to staff using \[status-review\], and how do I escalate them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/179041)

Answer (score 44):

I recognize that this is not a question, and that Philippe is only a messenger, but it needs to be said.

> I want to take a moment to say that the folks we laid off were **not** let go on the basis of poor performance. On the contrary, they are some of the best folks I have ever had the chance to work with. These are attractive hires, solid candidates, and affable, talented people. We’re grateful to have had the chance to work with them. They have our respect, and they deserve yours as well. I hope that we can count on you to do everything possible to ease their transition, beginning by not speculating as to who was cut and ‘why’.

It's downright insulting for the company to tell us this.

It's insulting that the company apparently has non-performance-related reasons for doing this. In my book, those would be the only possible good reasons.

It's insulting to be told (by implication) that we don't deserve information.

It's insulting to be teased with this lack of information, and then expected not to speculate.

It's insulting that the company describes layoffs as merely a "transition".

It adds insult to injury that this profound lack of transparency, couched in obnoxious HR-speak, comes at the same time that the layoffs include liaisons between the company and the community.

As others pointed out already, it adds insult to injury that the community are referred to (elsewhere) as "partners", even as we are continually further distanced and disrespected - when the site owes its existence to us.

Prashanth, I am not your "partner". I have had enough of this. Enjoy your AI-powered ghetto.

Comment: If it wasn't performance related, how did they choose? Randomly? By whose benefits were most expensive? It would have been better to say nothing about how people weren't selected. If it wasn't the lowest performing people or people working on things the company doesn't want to work on in the future, shouldn't shareholders be concerned that the lowest performers didn't get laid off? That statement was a big communication mistake IMO.

Comment: @ColleenV see Zoe answer for example. There is a clear "speculation" going on in the heads of many users. And obviously, being told to not speculate doesn't do much good to the speculation itself... quite the opposite - it only makes those speculations look more realistic.

Comment: Performance often isnt a factor in layoffs because it can be difficult to quantify.  Its more about making the money work, which teams can take the hit, and how they can restructure after X amount of employees are gone.  We would like to think if we work hard we wont get selected, but every layoff Ive seen has included a wide variety of people including those who were super high performers.

Comment: @JoshWolsborn Absolutely, which is why I think specifically mentioning that it wasn't about performance was a mistake. Everyone who's been through a layoff (which is a lot of us) knows how they work. The statement was well-meaning, but counter-productive. It's like saying "This tornado was definitely not man-made." Uh, ok sure I guess but why do you need to say that?

Comment: @JoshWolsborn Most big layoffs also don't fire who actually needs to be fired from a company.

Comment: A contrary view: I appreciated the note that it was not about performance. Philippe went out of his way to include praise for the laid-off people, acknowledging the great work they did for the company and removing any cloud of speculation around whether there were performance-related reasons that they were chosen; it was simply that there is no longer enough money in the budget for their role to exist. While I think eliminating these roles is a terrible mistake, I am at least glad that the people affected will enter their job search without that cloud over them. It's the least they deserve.

Comment: @RyanM Philippe could have praised them without weirdly stating "it wasn't because we thought they sucked at their job" and provoking the obvious follow-up question of "well why were these particular individuals chosen to be laid off then?"

Comment: I think Philippe did his best to praise us without actually revealing how the company/managers decided who to lay off. I understand folks wondering how they decided that, but I don't fault Philippe for saying nice things about us (and asking that folks not speculate about specific individuals).

Comment: @ColleenV One fairly common strategy is to simply lay off the most well paid employees first, as it minimizes the number of people affected for a given amount of costs saved, and is also objective and non-discriminatory (pay grade is not a protected class in any country I know of). Some may question the wisdom of effectively getting rid of your most senior employees first, but it still does happen here and there. (Of course, I'm not suggesting that this is what happened at SE, it's just a random example of a non-performance-based criterion.)

Comment: @TooTea Yep. People with families are more expensive benefits-wise which can put them at risk of being laid off when looking at "total compensation". I know how layoffs work; My point is that it was a communication error to say anything about the reason why someone may or may not have been chosen because I know how people work. The only reason this answer and all these comments exist is because of mentioning "poor performance". Laying off a bunch of people across the company is almost always financial and not due to individual performance.

Answer (score 43):

Is the experiment announced by Catija in “[If more users could vote, would they engage more? Testing 1 reputation voting on some sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393127/162827)” still underway, or has it been affected by her being laid off? What's the status of this experiment, and is there another community manager in charge? The Arqade community is very enthusiastic about this idea, as shown in the Arqade Meta post, “[Should Arqade opt-in to the 1 reputation voting experiment?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16891/4797)” Many of us at Arqade are looking forward to seeing it happen.

Aside from [Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16891/4797), [Graphic Design SE](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3850/176335) and [Pets SE](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2418/3255) are also volunteering for the experiment.

Comment: +1 - I would really like more detail on *"Projects undergoing active work may change scope or be canceled"* - even simply a list of project title -> status, what's ongoing/unchanged, what's been suspended/reduced in scope or shelved, and (apparently) what's being brought back from the dead. Although by the sounds of it the current priority is "keep the lights on" so I imagine most projects are in the 'suspended' state at the moment :(

Comment: That particular experiment also depended on a community willing to volunteer. It might be that this experiment is still hold back by a lack of such a community instead of being without staff now.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution "*That particular experiment also depended on a community willing to volunteer. It might be that this experiment is still hold back by a lack of such a community* " That's not the case. Actually, [Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16891/4797), [Graphic Design SE](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3850/176335), and [Pets SE](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2418/3255) are volunteering.

Answer (score 39):

Were the layoffs equally distributed among departments and roles or were they focused on specific areas like e.g. sales, development or a specific product?

Comment: And what does 28% mean in absolute numbers? They don't publish their Team page anymore, sadly, so it's hard to know if 28% is 28 people or 280 people or somewhere in between.

Comment: There were [over 500 employees before the first layoff](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/10/26/ceo-update-breaking-down-barriers-to-unlock-innovation/) (ctrl-f 500). 500 * 0.9 * 0.28 = 126 people fired is a very rough estimate. Probably worth adding a +-20-30% on that number (but probably on the higher end rather than the lower end)

Comment: @TylerH Good question to ask in its own answer.

Comment: In his blog post, Prashanth explained that todays round focused largely on our go-to-market operation.  They took a hard hit, but every single team in the company was impacted.

Comment: @Philippe "go-to-market operation" is Teams sales, right?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah.  But there were hard hits in other areas as well.  Our product  teams suffered a hit proportional to the size of the product org.  Lots of different areas are feeling it.  But yes, sales felt it the most this time.

Comment: The Verge -  https://www.theverge.com/2023/10/16/23919004/stack-overflow-layoff-ai-profitability

Comment: @user10186832 "coding help forum" yikes

Comment: @TylerH: Not much worse [than the CEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPbbt7Dg-2U&t=2m57) (at 02 min 57 secs)

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum He just repeats what’s written on the presentation.

Comment: @Zoeisonstrike re your math, I believe that last factor should be 1-0.28=0.72, right?

Comment: @Max No, because that would tell you how many employees are left, not how many were fired (which was the question at hand)

Comment: Actually though, I completely forgot/missed that the [previous round](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389060/332043) said "58, or about 10%". Assuming exactly 10% for convenience, and no new hires since,  gives 580 employees, yielding 580 * 0.9 * 0.28 = ~146 (which is well within the +-30% of the initial estimate, FWIW) employees that now suddenly have to look for a new job.  There's still an error here, though, but significantly less than +-30%

Answer (score 39):

Coming from a different region of the world, with much stronger labor laws, I always wonder why we seem to view layoffs so differently.

Where I come from, a layoff is stronger regulated and many things are out of control of the company. For example, you say your layoffs weren't performance related, but since you picked the people without any public criteria, that may or may not be the case, we will never know. Where I live, you have to set up public criteria (like age, number of dependents, salary, number of years in the company) and then select the people based on that.

Unless there is an equally public reason that cannot possibly be attributed to the company leadership (let’s say Corona lockdowns and airlines), a layoff is a very public admission of company and company leadership failure here. *Two* layoffs in a year certainly are. I'm not even sure when I heard about it the last time, except for companies that went belly up two months later.

Why is it that in the US, I never hear company leadership step down after such a failure? It's not SE alone, and I have not heard that from others either.

Can you shed some light on the cultural differences? Why is a layoff just something the leadership in the US shrugs off as something that just happens every few years?

Comment: Not all SE employees are based in the US.  ...  https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/508266/cesar-m

Comment: @user10186832 but it's a US company, so bound only to the US laws. Also, no need to go far, the CEO himself wasn't born in the USA. (though might be considered USA citizen by now, didn't check that deep.)

Comment: I'm not deep enough into their business to know whether they have local subsidiaries, hire their "staff" as self-employed, or have some other construct. I have no idea which labor laws apply for their remote workers. But since the company is a US company, they point of view of what is an acceptable "failure" (or if layoffs are even a "failure" at all) is certainly a US point of view.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry A US company is _not_ bound only to the US laws when it comes to hiring and employment practices.

Comment: (disclaimer: I was one of the employees laid off, but that’s unrelated to this comment). In a past life I was a manager at a different company and was told many times by corporate legal/HR that you basically never give reasons/criteria for firing someone unless specifically required to. The US is a very litigious nation and that info will often lead to lawsuits.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I'm not a lawyer so can't know for sure, but common sense does day that if an employee is hired by a USA company, that employee can be laid off according to the rules of USA, not wherever they live. The contract is personal, between the company and the employee. If there is an existing blog/article explaining otherwise, I'd be happy to read and learn.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry [The laws of both countries apply](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/80890/5041). Otherwise that would be a massive loophole to bypass labour law.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 with all due respect, the answer there is given by private person, being a mod on Law.SE does not make them lawyer. So that's not anything close to reliable source.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry There's little room for "common sense" when the law is involved. Speaking from extensive personal experience, at least in the EU, it's where the work actually takes place that determines the applicable labour law, regardless of where the employer has its headquarters. My employer was forced (yes, that involved actual legal analysis) to basically set up a one-man subsidiary in my country of residence just so they could legally have me work for them from home. There are entire companies specializing in setting up such "proxy employers".

Comment: @TooTea I see, and glad to hear. Can only hope the non-USA employees of Stack Exchange are treated properly, according to their local laws, which are most likely better than the USA.

Comment: @nvoight what you list as criteria for letting go would be illegal in the UK and I would guess EU. You have to close down a job - ie do less things and the let go the people doing that job. It does not matter how well or bad the employee was or any details about them.

Comment: @mmmmmm No it is not. It's actually *mandatory* in Germany. When you remove a *job* (compared to a *person*), you have to pick objective criteria and publish them. None of the criteria say anything about whether or not the specific person was good at their job though.

Comment: @nvoigt Ok in Uk performance can't be used as layoff criteria but neither can you use  (like age, number of dependents, salary, number of years in the company) . The only criteria is does the job exist after the layoffs.

Comment: @mmmmmm What happens when you remove 5 out of 10 developer jobs? Can the company just pick who they like best? In Germany, the company has to prove that they *did not* pick for performance.

Comment: They have to stop the prjects those developers are on - I don't know what happens if all are doing the same thing.

Comment: @mmmmmm Mr experience and understanding (in the UK) aligns with nvoigt's - if you are reducing the number of employees who are in the same role, you have to create measurable criteria, and rank the candidates. It's actually for exactly the reason John M. Wright gave: secrecy isn't enough, you need to be ready to answer any legal challenge with evidence that you followed a fair process.

Answer (score 37):

> We’re seeing some positive signs around uptake for our new OverflowAI
> features, and today’s actions will allow us to be more strategic and
> to narrow our focus as we move forward. Expect to see a continued
> focus on OverflowAI as we build it toward commercial viability.

Do you have any tangible proof about those positive signs or this is just bad case of wishful thinking? Because I am not seeing any improvements in the OverflowAI functionality since the initial release.

And if by uptake you mean, people trying the thing to see how it works, then is it really an uptake?

Do you really want to keep pouring all your money betting on the dead horse hoping for some kind of miracle?

Comment: Yeah, wasting everyone's time with OverflowAI is part of why the community is so nervous in the first place, and if this is anything like the MDN case, you're (at best) just seeing people who haven't realized that what the "AI" made for them is just a bunch of words stuck together in a way that superficially resembles the training data, augmented by the prompt.

Comment: ([Link to MDN issue](https://github.com/mdn/yari/issues/9208) for context)

Answer (score 34):

### What, if any, pay cut have folks on the C-suite level taken in response to these financial issues?

I generally find the actions of such layoffs a lot more reasonable when it's not just the rank and files losing their income stream alone. And if pay cuts haven't occurred on the C-suite level, why hasn't this occurred?

Comment: Not quite a direct answer, but Phillipe has [mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393806/practical-effects-of-the-october-2023-layoff?cb=1#comment1317586_393988) that any pay cuts would have needed to be *"very very substantial"* as personnel costs amount to around 80% of their total budget. But I agree it would've been nice to see it from the C-level folk especially.

Comment: @Robotnik did you mean to post a different link? The one you provided links to this post.

Comment: hmm, it's a comment link, no idea why it doesn't link back to the comment now. Possibly it was deleted?

Comment: Oh, it's on a downvoted answer so it probably ended up on the second page of answers (depending on how you have your answers sorted). I'm guessing on load, the page couldn't find the comment, and so loaded the top of the page instead. Here's a direct link to the answer, Philipe's comment is below it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393988/179041

Answer (score 32):

For any company, multiple large layoffs within a single calendar year are an extremely concerning sign. Following the round [this past May](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/05/10/a-message-from-prashanth-chandrasekar-ceo-stack-overflow/), I hoped that the company's strategic plan would avoid another; that was obviously not the case.

[Yesterday's blog post by Prashanth](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/10/16/stack-overflow-company-announcement-october-2023/) announcing the October layoffs contains the following section:

> This year is no different, ranging from the monumental efforts to successfully launch OverflowAI to dealing with the ongoing threats to customer budgets shifting due to the macroeconomic pressures impacting the entire tech industry. This is why we have been so focused on our path to profitability, even as we commit to the continued product innovation of Stack Overflow for Teams and the health of the public platform by building out our AI/ML capabilities. This year we took many steps to spend less. Unfortunately, those changes were not enough[.]

Speaking as specifically as possible, to what factors, plans and strategic decisions since May does the company ascribe this latest layoff, and how will it change course going forward, beyond of course these layoffs? Was it doubling down on investing resources in AI, problems with sales, etc.? I'd like to have a better picture of what there is to learn here and where we're headed, since it feels like there's uncertainty everywhere.

Succinctly put, how did the company get from May to now, and how will SO avoid more layoffs in, say, another five months?

Comment: For an economy too... where's the advertised "soft landing" I wonder?

Comment: Especially concerning is that the second RIF was bigger than the first.  18% RIF followed by 3% 6 months later?  No big deal.  8% followed by 20%?  Bad sign.  (And SO's is even bigger than that)

Answer (score 31):

From the [blog:](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/10/16/stack-overflow-company-announcement-october-2023/)

> This year is no different, ranging from the monumental efforts to successfully launch OverflowAI to dealing with the ongoing threats to customer budgets shifting due to the macroeconomic pressures impacting the entire tech industry. This is why we have been so focused on our path to profitability, even as we commit to the continued product innovation of Stack Overflow for Teams and the health of the public platform by building out our AI/ML capabilities.

Translation:

> We have fired a bunch of people so that we can continue to piss away vast quantities of money on AI hype.

Comment: I mean, they have to focus on money because Prosus spent $1.8 billion acquiring SO. That's a lot of money to make back, and then they also want a profit afterward.

Comment: Firing people won't help much.  Assume each person fired was earning $100000.  You'd have to fire 18000 people to save that $1.8 billion. [Apaprently, something like 140 people were fired.](https://siliconangle.com/2023/10/16/stack-overflow-lets-go-28-workforce-cost-reduction-push/) Assuming they all earned $100000 per year (a serious overestimate,) then that'd save Stack a grand total of $14 million dollars. per year.  It'll only take 128 years at that rate to pay back the $18 billion.

Answer (score 31):

We are all aware of many platforms (far beyond Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange) that once provided an excellent service to their users but afterwards started to degrade. Cory Doctorow calls this phenomenon [Enshittification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enshittification) and ascribes it to greedy capitalist platform hosts that want to monetise their communities as much as they can. And in the next step, the advertisers are trapped and monetised, too. Some platforms are too big to fail, and others are left by their former users and go into oblivion.

Having said this, I hope that SO/SE does not go down this road, because I find their service still valuable.

P.S. [A new piece by Cory Doctorow on Enshittifiaction and the Labour Market](https://pluralistic.net/2023/11/25/moral-injury/)

Comment: It's hard for SE to trap and monetise their advertisers, because ads aren't provided directly [whatever _this_ was notwithstanding](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425384/5223757). Iirc Stack Exchange is part of the Google Display Network.

Comment: "I hope that SO/SE does not go down this road" - to quote the late and great Douglas Adams, "There is another theory which states that this has already happened."

Answer (score 30):

Of the four "Chosen Spokespersons" listed, one doesn't even appear to have an SE account, one hasn't been seen for over a month, and I don't find a response here by the third. The only "Chosen Spokesperson" to make any sort of response is Phillipe.

Why were the three C-level persons listed as Chosen Spokespersons if they (appear to have) had no intention of Speaking to the beloved community?

Yes, any response they made would no doubt have been followed up with embarrassing follow on questions, but this appears to me to have been yet another false impression of caring given to us, the regular community.

Comment: I created the list of spokespeople, and I did it based upon what areas I thought questions would focus on. It was always my intent to handle the majority of the questions here, but if there was a need for a voice from the legal team, I wanted to be able to very quickly get answers from a designated person there, and have you know they were authoritative.  Same with the technology team, and the CEO.  As it turns out, I have been able to field them myself, or take them to an SME (like the diversity question) and bring back an answer.

Comment: @Philippe So we have no hope of having any sort of answer directly from Prashanth regarding this mess? Nothing against you, Philippe. I'm aware you're doing the best you can, but for the community it appears that management, in the form of Prashanth is outright ignoring us. It is not helping the community sentiment at all.

Answer (score 29):

In the past, Stack Overflow has put some significant efforts into hiring a diverse workforce. In particular, when I started on the DBRE team at Stack Overflow, I was quite proud of the company's diversity in terms of gender & sexual orientation, and while racial diversity was not necessarily industry-leading, the company was executing quite well at hiring and maintaining a diverse workforce.

##### Recognizing the importance of a diverse workplace can you provide some aggregate numbers on how the February, May, and October layoffs have affected the company's workforce diversity?

Ideally, I would like to see the top-level numbers for these "big three" diversity measures (race, gender, sexual orientation), for the company as a whole at the start of the year vs now vs the makeup of the large combined cohort of laid-off former-Stackers.

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Is sexual orientation really reliable known in US based companies? Where I come from, you're not allowed to ask for anything like that, so the number is largely unknown and a change in that number could hardly be measured. Is this possible in the US?

Comment: Race & sexual orientation are both _voluntary_ questions, and sometimes collected during _anonymous_ surveys. Regardless, it's considered an important DEIB metric for companies to track. As a former employee, I don't actually recall how Stack collected this info. If it was during anonymous surveys, the company might be limited to Year-over-year numbers.  The [HRC Equality Index scoring algorithm](https://www.hrc.org/resources/corporate-equality-index-criteria)  (section 3b) includes this type of data collection as part of rating employers' LGBTQ friendliness.

Comment: Does the DEIB metric translate to any meaningful increase in productivity or adversely impact productivity?

Comment: @TheMaster try googling "studies on diversity in the workplace" ... my top result starts "A McKinsey & Company study showed that companies in the top 25% for racial/ethnic and gender diversity were respectively 36% and 25% more likely to have superior financial returns. "

Comment: I spoke with our Director of Divesity, Equity, Inclusion and Belonging and showed her this question.  Here's her reply: "Beginning in April of 2023, we began reporting demographic data internally to all staff, and we will continue to report representation data - as well as progress on key Diversity, Equity, Inclusion and Belonging (DEIB) initiatives - internally every six months. One of the challenges we've faced with reporting is large gaps in employee self-ID data, which is shared voluntarily. ...

Comment: ...Because we're a global company, there are a number of demographics we cannot ask for countries we have employees in, and there are also some demographics that are outside the cultural norm to request in some countries. To keep our data gathering scalable for our relatively small People Ops team, we currently ask consistent questions for all geographies. We feel that data reporting is an important step in our journey to accountability and for gauging the efficacy of our DEIB programs....

Comment: ... While we don't have imminent plans to begin reporting that information externally, it is something that is on our five-year timeline; meanwhile, we will continue to work on closing data gaps, creating consistent and reliable internal reporting, and measuring the success of our key DEIB initiatives. "

Comment: @Philippe To ask a followup, based on the self-reporting data that you DO have, was Stack careful to monitor for potential (implicit) bias in identifying individuals to be laid off? Equitable hiring practices are important, but I personally feel that equitable employment & termination are a more important factor, given the extremely high "drop out rate" of women, POC, and gender queer folks in the Tech industry in the US.

Comment: @Philippe To be perfectly blunt, I assume the company considered demographics as it relates to underrepresented groups & members of what US non-discrimination law considers "protected classes" -- failure to do so would be a glaring misstep as discrimination (implicit or overt) would open the company up to potential legal action by those impacted. Perhaps you could shed some light on how Stack ensured that bias was eliminated from the process of selecting persons to be laid off.

Comment: the spelling error was mine, thanks for catching it.  @AMtwo - I'll provide your follow up questions to her and see what response she'd like to make.

Answer (score 28):

I noticed in [the recent blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/10/16/stack-overflow-company-announcement-october-2023) by Prashanth Chandrasekar, there was no thanks given to those that were part of the most recent layoff. I feel like in general when making an announcement about a layoff, the company thanks the workers affected for their work over the years, and was wondering if there was a reason this wasn't included as part of the blog post.

The way it is worded currently makes the layoffs seem like a side note, with the main focus being on the the development of AI/ML capabilities and the working for more profitability for next year.

Comment: It would be nice if @Prashanth, in your role as one of the dedicated spokespeople on this issue, could address this directly. I feel like this is a pretty big misstep to not even take a moment to (publicly) thank all those affected.

Answer (score 26):

In the [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/10/16/stack-overflow-company-announcement-october-2023/), we can read the following:

> To our community members and customers reading this note: you are foundational to our success. Thank you for *your continued partnership* as we enter this next phase.

I thought our hierarchic relationship had been made pretty clear since recent and less recent indiscretions: **how are community members now considered partners?**

Answer (score 24):

> **The community isn’t going anywhere**

I did, years ago, after what you, the Company(tm), did to M.Cellio.

Comment: I mostly dipped after Prosus bought SO. I still come around occasionally & leave a couple comments, but I'm not hanging out & answering questions for fun.

Comment: @Reed Same here. My actual contributions go elsewhere, as mentioned in my profile.

Comment: To clarify, it's my SO profile, not my Meta profile.

Answer (score 23):

When reading the following parts:

> On October 16th, 2023, Stack Exchange laid off roughly 28% of its workforce. This follows a previous lay-off of 10% in April.

> Projects undergoing active work may change scope or be canceled.

> Because every team in the company was impacted by these cuts, every single team’s workflow is going to change. You can reasonably expect some delays as we adjust.

I came across the question how much the development team is impacted.

Aside from Community Management, the dev team is very important to the Community as they are the ones building new features. With the phrasing, I get a feel that the dev team got hit very hard.

So, how much impact is there on the dev team? Can we get concrete numbers on that? Especially numbers regarding the people working on the public Q&A would be interesting.

Comment: I don't have concrete numbers, as I was a part of the April layoff, but it seems this round was more focused on designers and sales.  Engineering took the big hit in April.  Some devs were impacted by this but so far I have seen very few.

Comment: Thank you. It's good to see that it at least didn't effect the dev team that much.

Comment: Looked in the list of completed bugs here, sifted over the pages, and luckily didn't find even single developer (who posted here) that was laid off. Maybe some did in the Teams department, or those who didn't post here, but looks like they took a lesser hit.

Answer (score 23):

According to [The Verge](https://www.theverge.com/2023/10/16/23919004/stack-overflow-layoff-ai-profitability):

> Word of the layoffs comes over a year after the company made a big hiring push, doubling its size to over 500 people.

Is this accurate? **If so, what accountability will there be for the leaders who upended so many people's lives through such spectacularly poor planning?**

Comment: That's not a valid point, you work, they fire you, you search for another job. Its not like stackoverflow would have kept them forever, or they wouldn't leave for a better deal.

Comment: @Or4ng3h4t It is absolutely a valid point. Lots of people would leave very stable jobs they had for a _chance_ at working at a place with such a prestigious name like Stack Overflow had. Now those people are jobless. It's not as if SO was "just another company" like every other out there. The name has weight, it carries a promise that was now broken to several people.

Comment: It might be cultural, but not a single person I know would want to work for SO, Google, Facebook, X etc., those companies suck life out of you, always has been, they take their developers as cheap as they can get them, use them, they feel burnout, fire them, repeat.

Answer (score 20):

### Why are you cutting your sales team if your goal is more sales?

From the CEO's blog post:

> As I mentioned, **our focus for this fiscal year and into the next is profitability** and that, along with macroeconomic pressures led to today’s changes.

and

> As such, we are significantly **reducing the size of our go-to-market organization while we do so**. Supporting teams and other teams across the organization are impacted as well.

How do these two fit together? You have a platform that has been around for a decade. It would seem if your primary goal is short therm profitablity, then the sales team is the last thing you should be cutting, and investment into development or other areas like middle management that have not such a direct impact on sales in the short term, is what you should be doing.

Comment: Teams sales (what the "go-to-market org" refers to) is not necessarily the only option or even the most desired option for profitability, in terms of the board's perspective. If no new customers are buying SO Teams, do you want to keep paying for 50 people in a Teams Sales department, for example? Or do you want to reduce that team down to 10 people until sales pick back up again? (NB - I don't know how many people were in that team or how many were laid off, the numbers here are just examples).

Comment: @TylerH How else is SO making money? The site is free, and does not use advertising, at least I never saw any.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin i mean. there's absolutely ads. Has been for what... 10? 12? years?

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin Ads, sponsorships, collectives, SO Enterprise if that's still a thing, existing SO Teams (Sales reps are for typically _new_ customers, not maintaining existing ones), plus general funding from their owner, Prosus. Honestly I think they should bring back Careers/Jobs as that was a great product and one that fit well into the theme of SO and its general marketing "plan" of collecting all the programming knowledge in one place. That could be what OP is talking about above with "one feature may be returning soon".

Comment: @KevinB Thanks for the explanation - I am nostly on RPG.SE, which does not have any, but if other sites do, that is of course an explanation.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that makes sense then. Sorry! yea SO has had ads forever, it's a very large portion of SO's revenue stream. Certainly not *all* of their revenue, of course, but enough for them to care about doing something about the decline in engagement.

Comment: @TylerH I loved SO Careers (got at least one job out of it), but one of the things I heard from people at SO was that they had trouble getting hiring people to care about the SO aspect of it.  To HR and non-technical people, SO Careers was just another place they had to pay to post a job ad.  I was hoping it would provide deeper insight into technical and communication capabilities when hiring, but none of the people who contacted me via SO careers ever looked at my SO activity -- by the time engineers were looking at my resume, it was entirely removed from SO.

Answer (score 20):

**Tell me about the money. What are the financial figures?**

1. How much money will you save per-year due to these layoffs?
2. How much revenue do you get per-year?
3. What are your revenue/profit goals annually?
4. What portion of your revenue goes to high-paid executives, making $200k or more per year?

Comment: Some older numbers, from before the acquisition: [A previous revelation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMfxd9y0cMY&t=15m57s) stated [16 USD million in 2018 in ad revenue (mostly Azure)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMfxd9y0cMY&t=22m20s) out of [44 USD million in 2018](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMfxd9y0cMY&t=21m45s). There may or may not be information about Jobs revenue in there. But Jobs probably couldn't achieve the [stated goal of 700 USD million](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMfxd9y0cMY&t=15m57s). Jobs is mentioned from 20 min 58 secs.

Comment: cont' - (Ad avoidance information: [00 min 00 secs - 00 min 52 secs], [09 min 18 secs - 11 min 33 secs], [28 min 40 secs - 30 min 58 secs], and [43 min 54 secs - 45 min 47 secs].)

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum thanks. Yeah, I see he says somebody's gotta take them from 70 million to 700 million, then take it public. I hate it lol. 70 million's gotta be plenty revenue to actually run StackOverflow, but probably not enough to make investors happy, hence the acquisition, i guess.

Comment: I will ask for these numbers but I will say upfront that I don't expect to be able to publish non-public data here. But I'll ask and see what, if anything,  I can get.

Comment: @Philippe, thank you for working on it. Were you able to get the numbers?

Answer (score 19):

StackOverflow [announced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351385/ceo-blog-some-exciting-news-about-fundraising) some funding 3 years ago: $85m.

If that were all spent by now (I'm not saying it is; just for reference) that equates to spending over $2.5m/month.

I think some people might have the following question: how is this even remotely possible for a site that was already built to run efficiently, with a strong volunteer community that was extremely self-sustaining? How can a CEO raise that much money, and deliver so poorly that repeated layoffs are necessary?

Why not strip back to core ops and dev teams, a 2-person design team, 3 product people, one of whom is CPO, and reinvest in community? This place was working when the CEO and more recent senior management team inherited it. It's now not.

Comment: `Why not strip back` because it changed hands for $1.8bn in the meantime

Comment: @Pekka sounds like Twitter case: bought for insane amount, which caused the buyer to go on layoff spree to cut his losses. (At least here in SE employees still have toilet paper in the toilets. I hope.)

Comment: "This place was working when the CEO and more recent senior management team inherited it. It's now not" The management team is supposed to sell the company at a value higher than when it was bought. To have a working place is not in their immediate interest.

Comment: @EarlGrey I don't think it's worth speculating about that; I do think the CEO should take the hit and resign for spending so much money on things people wanted that wouldn't help.

Comment: @RobGrant exactly, there is no need to speculate, if you check the CEO profile https://stackoverflow.co/company/leadership/prashanth-chandrasekar you will understand the CEO expertise and that they will not take any hit, at worst they may not get a bonus, by failing their goals of "driving Stack Overflow’s overall strategic direction and results".
The layoff however aligns with it and with "Our focus for this fiscal year is on profitability [...] along with macroeconomic pressures, led to today’s changes." reason given for the previous layoff. I see Santa bringing a big bonus for the CEO...

Comment: The course for the current situation was set back in 2010 when it was decided to take on Venture Capital. Everything bad (from the community's perspective) that has happened since was probably an inevitable consequence of full-on joining 21st century US corporate culture and the pressure to hopefully, eventually go 100x. Had the decision been taken back then to trudge on with a skeleton crew, in the style of early-days Wikipedia, and focus on being a library for the world, maybe things would have worked out differently. Who knows!

Comment: @EarlGrey why? Has SO made a profit?

Comment: @RobGrant you do not need to make a profit to sell a company at a higher price than when you bought it.  See Twitter: in 2009 its valuation was ~1 billion. In 2017 its value was ~17 bilion (of which only 7bilion of "tangible" assets).
How much profit made twitter between 2009 and 2017. Zero. It was burning money. Its net income was always negative. This did not prevent the management to get bonuses for reaching arbitrarily estabilished goals, backed by the increased valuation of the company and its financing by investors.

Comment: @EarlGrey sure, but you're claiming that the SO CEO has done well. Why do you say that?

Comment: @RobGrant I am not saying the CEO did well. I am saying the CEO and the managment are doing what they know to do to increase profitability, achieving *their* goals. Their two blog posts about firing people are copy&paste (May https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/05/10/a-message-from-prashanth-chandrasekar-ceo-stack-overflow/ and now https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/10/16/stack-overflow-company-announcement-october-2023/ ) Firing people while having some customers with contract in place is a sure way to increase it. If there will be new customers after these contracts end, who knows and *who cares*?

Comment: @EarlGrey this seems to be a generic rant, unrelated to your claim that the CEO will get a big bonus for the company performance. If that was also just a generic rant that's fine; I'd rather you just said so, so I can stop assuming you've got info.

Comment: @RobGrant general rant? I have nothing to rant, I have just been close to too many startups in their expansion&exit phase ... the CEO is not known to do spectacular things, just to follow what is coming from money bringer, see as an example https://www.teamblind.com/post/Opinions-on-Prashanth-Chandrasekar-46kyDzg5

Comment: @RobGrant on the other hand, you seem to have a general unfounded rant against the CEO: " This place was working when the CEO and more recent senior management team inherited it. It's now not." 
The CEO has been hired to fulfill certain goals. These goals are not what you consider relevant, and unless you are investing 85M in the company your consideration are unfortunately not relevant ...

Comment: @EarlGrey I'm asking what those goals are, given you're saying he'll get a bonus for fulfilling them.

Comment: The goal  is **Profitability**, it is written in two different blog posts, the CEO is known for his strong performance in M&A, it is simple logic to see how the goals are exactly defined and why the CEO was rationally picked among the large pool of candidates for the position.

Comment: @EarlGrey understood - so are you saying that the CEO has achieved that, and that's why he'll get a bonus? What was the profitability?

Comment: If increase in profit is n/a, reduction in opex will bring up profitability, when current contracts can be honored.
So you can fire people, ideally aiming at "stripping back to core ops and dev teams", since it was working before, it may work in the future ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1735/discussion-between-rob-grant-and-earlgrey).

Answer (score 16):

> Our responses to you will be temporarily disrupted.
>
> Everyone in the company will be involved in managing this transition. Because every team in the company was impacted by these cuts, every single team’s workflow is going to change. You can reasonably expect some delays as we adjust.

This seems to have been the standard every time the community received bad news, so thanks for the transparency this time, I guess. But doesn't this also mean you have too few employees to properly deal with changes in the company to begin with?

Furthermore, managing workflows and the responsibilities of separate teams seems to me something that should be handled in advance of laying off people, not afterwards; how thought-out was this decision?

Comment: Just speaking practically here, I think that no matter how you slice it, a 28% layoff is not going to be an easy time for the employees at the company. In terms of how we organize, managers within the company received instructions after the layoff as to how they will reorganize, and are sharing them with their teams. This will take time and energy to manage - it's a major project for everyone in the company to adapt. But it's also our highest priority...

Comment: ...Our intent is not to neglect public communications, but I wrote this post in the spirit of honesty and transparency, and in that spirit it needs to be said that when push comes to shove, the practical first priority has to be managing the internal transition.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, @Philippe. I realize there must be the necessary adjustment after the layoff when the practical side of the matter kicks in, but it just struck me as strange that continuing communication towards the community (as "one of the most reliable cornerstones") was an apparently overlooked/unanticipated aspect of it all. Maybe I overestimated the timespan suggested in the above quote. [cont.]

Comment: [cont.] Then again, you have been active here, which is very much appreciated—as is the transparency. Nevertheless, can you still expand on how the current workload will be coped with, with this now much smaller team )especially in regards to the community and the online platform)? Or is that something that will be addressed in more detail elsewhere?

Comment: We'll be expanding on that more in future posts (at least for the community team, and probably - i'm guessing on this though - the product org).  Since we haven't yet had a chance to inform everyone involved of changes in assignments, I dont want to jump the gun here.

Answer (score 15):

Ok, so what I see here is a young man with a bright future going "Oooh shiny!" for a gold rush and selling his mother on the black market to buy a good shovel and pickaxe, and heading to the mines.

My question is, what is Stack Exchange's plan for the plausible future where all of this was a big bubble and there wasn't that much gold in the mine after all? What if you dig and it's all dirt and cobble?

**To be more clear:** Does Stack Exchange leadership take the community for granted? Are you guys really sure this AI thing you've got going will pan out? Let's say, the future is [Mojo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojo_(programming_language)), or [Bun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bun_(software)), or some other new language, and nobody is posting here anymore because you burnt all trust. What then? Hope Microsoft buys you?

Comment: It seems unlikely that Prosus will accept what Microsoft could possibly pay at this juncture. The spiel now is to degrade the investment so it can be sold off at a loss when it's really clear that they paid too much for it.

Answer (score 14):

For anyone impacted by this RIF, I would like to offer my support. Please comment here or reach out to me on LinkedIn (https://www.linkedin.com/in/sscovil/) and I will do whatever I can to help boost your signal, make introductions to folks in my network, and try to connect you with other opportunities.

I've been a longtime user of Stack Overflow. I've also been through several layoffs at previous companies, and know how difficult and frightening it can be. This community is bigger than the company that created it, and communities come together in difficult times. Let me know how I can help.

Comment: *[RIF](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/RIF#Noun)*

Comment: I’m not a recruiter.

Answer (score 12):

I took offense when you [dismissed  Nikolay](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12700/532877). Now, I am even more in shock. You dismissed  27% of staff because you want to amass more money. What's next? Will you continue? I suppose so.

I see you. I see only money in your eyes.

Comment: SO is "for profit", money is how they work, without money no jobs.... people wont work for free in the country where SO is located.

Answer (score 12):

What will happen? I am not sure; I imagine as Stack Overflow continues this trend of 'caring' for the community, eventually that community will move to alternatives.

An example of an alternative that I have found myself pulled to is Codidact.com which is equivalent in terms of technology/interactive experience to Stack Exchange, though it lacks the Google/GitHub/Facebook sign ins (which are nice). And, more importantly has significantly fewer members.

What alternatives have you found?

Answer (score 12):

This feels like just a repetition of previous answers, but I don't think it has received a credible response.

If it wasn't for performance reasons (because you say so in the announcement) and it's not that you *specifically wanted to get rid of* personnel who was rooting for the community (because those are certainly the optics from where I'm looking) ... what other reasons could remain?

Comment: It's obviously about money

Comment: I think we've been fairly upfront: this action was taken to cut costs.

Comment: Many years ago I worked for Signetics, a subsidiary of Philips Semiconductors. When Philips decided to close Signetics and its Orem, UT facility, in at least the case of our design team, they fired nearly all of the senior personnel, leaving myself and a handful of college graduates as the core of the design team. The people they fired were brilliant engineers - but they were trying to save money and we were cheap. I suspect they believed they could hold on to most of the market share (of our team) while we "came up to speed." In other words, this actually happens, but it doesn't bode well.

Comment: Yes, of course you reduce personnel to cut costs, but when you do, you also decide which personnel to reduce. That's what this question is _obviously_ about.

Comment: @tripleee I think the most likely explanation is that their current projects did not overlap with the top priorities of the company, which is troubling because those projects included those that interact intimately with the public sites and curator/moderator community (e.g. mod tooling, testing the consequences of rep changes for voting), but also not surprising because those do not overlap with the short-term money makers and company priorities (Teams, Collectives, "AI"). Also an incredibly short-sighted (though seemingly industry-typical) way to do layoffs.

Comment: @Philippe I assumed [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393806/practical-effects-of-the-october-2023-layoff?page=1&tab=modifieddesc#comment1317637_393819) was quite clear yet this imho look like another attempt to answer a different question. This user, like everyone else is not asking WHY you cut the number of employees - that hopefully should be clear. They are asking ***how you choose who got laid-off*** since it is not a secret that from the outside it looks like you are cherry-picking some key figures that were closer to the community (see shog9 before this).

Comment: @Philippe [cont] obviously you are free to say that you can't disclose this because those are private detail and I will accept that but... please don't treat us fool. This question didn't ask why you did this and you probably know that.

Comment: @Philippe Glassdoor exists. What CM's are paid is a drop in the bucket, and doesn't not justifiy firing them to "save costs".

Answer (score 12):

I believe the culprit here is AI. There, I've said it. However, this move can backfire.

First off, let’s put ourselves in SO shoes: You own the biggest Q&A sites in the history of Q&A sites. You *have* a lot of human curated *data*. You are concerned about web scraping and it being used to train [LLMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_language_model). Right? It's your data after all, and you don't want to give it away for free and a side effect will certainly a steep decrease in traffic to your sites. What can you do?

Use AI yourself to cut costs. I think this is the general direction.

Where is this short-sighted?

1. AI trained without human curation is not performant and eventually these huge expensive models will (re)introduce some of that in their huge training databases.
2. AI can't assert correctness deterministically. Therefore it can be easily swindled into error and it almost never recovers by itself.
3. Trust with the community is broken.
4. If SO survives, it will have to start over.

I hope this isn't some suits chasing the big bucks. That will fail. You aren't making silicon chips; you are a Q and A site collection.

Ever heard of the [New York City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_City) PC repair shop that, despite top-tier equipment and staff, struggled to make ends meet? Somehow along the way it forgot it was a computer repair shop. The point is, if a Q&A site is struggling to make a profit, it is because it is probably too big or their margins too high, or its investments too bad. Something. Sorry for not ending on a cheerful note.

Comment: Re *"the New York City PC repair shop"*: [Louis Rossman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Rossmann)? [Sample YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0qbrLiGY4Cg). Wasn't that mostly for Apple devices?

Comment: You think you have to hyperlink New York in case some people are unfamiliar with this city, but not the obscure PC shop you are apparently alluding to?

Comment: I'm sorry, the hyperlinking was a complete accident. The point was the important bit. Different business should expect different profit margins, even in 2023. Maximising profit at all costs is the most expensive thing to do. And acting out of FOMO isn't good either. Hopefully everyone laid off will still be ok.

Answer (score 11):

Sounds like you're firing people who get paid a lot and substituting them with lower paid positions and AI/ML.

Comment: No, there's no intention to replace the laid off staff with lower-cost options.  That... is rather evil.  If I were to find out that a situation like you describe was planned, I would not be standing here in front of you, because I would immediately depart. Luckily, no one in our management would even dream of that, I'm fairly comfortable saying, and I truly believe that the company would never take an action such as you suggest.  And I feel confident in saying that Prashanth would never sign off on that.

Comment: Then, the lost jobs are just lost? So if we had 100 people doing something now we have 72? What's the impact? (e.g. Slower response time or whatever)

Answer (score 10):

Would the company consider spinning off the public sites as a non-profit? The cost of running the servers is surely a small fraction of the company's expenses and could surely be covered by the community (especially if we knew what it cost). And if the company isn't willing to properly invest in the community team, then maybe it would be better to just let the community run itself? Without diminishing the work that our CMs have done, it has been a small team. Even if every CM's workload required 10 times as many volunteers, I think the network is large enough to have that many trusted people. Obviously it wouldn't be easy to run a network of this size as a non-profit, but it would be worth considering at least.

Comment: Except my (totally an outsider) hunch is that the nominal value of SE is based on the *traffic* provided by the public sites. Without the public sites to provide (a) viewers/clickers of ads, (b) recommendations to companies to set up their own private instances (Teams), etc. there is little value to the rest of the company.

Comment: I think we could afford to re-hire the CMs part-time: a Stack Exchange Charitable Foundation would probably get a _lot_ of grant money.

Comment: FWIW - i have some experience in this area, having worked at the Wikimedia Foundation for the better part of a decade.  Raising money is HARD and while Wikipedia does it pretty well, we purposely walked AWAY from grants because they came with an expectation that donors could influence our direction, and we weren't comfortable with that.  And truly unencumbered large donations were few and far between.  People like to give for shiny projects, but few give to pay the water bill. Might be harder than you suggest.

Comment: @Philippe The Wikimedia Foundation hit its Endowment goal well in advance of schedule, and receives far more than its actual running costs. No one would donate to SE when it's run as it is now, but with solid community leadership it would certainly be possible. No guarantee of course, but it's quite possible the network could fund itself.

Comment: Sure.  It's quite possible.  It's certainly possible fund itself - but the point i am making is that it would likely need to be individual donors, not grant monies that do it.

Answer (score 6):

> Projects undergoing active work may change scope or be canceled.

and

> Short-term priorities may shift towards reliability and maintenance.

and

> That means we’ll still prioritize bug-fixes as usual

If your capacities are indeed so much compromised now, I suggest rolling back the recent ["colors change" project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393939/908360).

[My observation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394017/908360) is that

- that change had made things significantly worse (in terms of ergonomy / eye strain), and
- the number of bugs seem to prognostize a long-term ongoing struggle towards a direction that currently, already, looks like a step backwards from what this site had beforehand.

When a budget running out is a realistic threat, you may find it a better choice to get stuck at that point with something that is at least usable and inviting-looking — and not this current version that is inducing strong eye-strain, to name only its biggest issue.

The way this effort kicked off, might warn of a long-term ongoing struggle with bugs and unplanned revisions.

I find, under other circumstances, it could be straightforward to march on and smoothen out wrinkles as you go, but with a faltering budget, the option to roll back to the latest stable and usable UI, and re-contemplate any next steps from there, is also worth a thought.

Answer (score 4):

Can Stack Exchange Inc. explain the impact of the layoff on the Community-a-thon 2023 event?

What message is the company trying to send to the community, by holding Community-a-thon (an event which was started to "*Improve empathy between all Stack Overflow employees and our sites and communities*") on one hand, and laying off staff on the other hand at the same time?

Clearly, you are not sending the right message to the community.

Comment: We considered this.  Rosie is in charge of community-a-thon this year, and I asked her what she wanted to do about it.  Not long after that, V2blast actually weighed in (his accounts hadn't been deactivated yet) and made a fairly clear statement that he thought it should go forward, which matched Rosie's feeling as well - we honor those who have left us by going forward with the things that are already in flight, whenever we can. At the end of the day, it was a judgment call, but I think it's the right one. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: "We honor those who have left us" sounds amazingly like "don't do x or the terrorists win" that we heard all the time in the decade following 9/11. Honoring the laid off, honestly, should have next to no impact on whether or not an event happens. What needs be considered, first and foremost, is simply: _Can it happen at all, with the reduced staff_,? followed by _how much overtime, legitimate or otherwise, will this cause the remaining staff to work_? When considering the hours over 40 (overtime), I'm not only talking about monetary costs, but burn out and other work/life separation issues.

Comment: @Philippe "those who have left us" doesn't sound right. It sounds as if the employees resigned, but in reality, they were laid off.

Answer (score -3):

Did you ask the entire staff if they'd take a cut in pay in order to avoid layoffs before dropping the ax?

Comment: Wouldn't that be based on whether or not the true and only impetus for the removal of staff was cost?

Comment: I am not an accountant, but the limited amount that I know about the situation indicates that the pay cut would need to be very very substantial.  It's not just the cost of salaries, it's the total cost of employing people - insurance, training, computers, benefits.... and personnel costs around something like 80% of our total budget.  The total costs (and therefore the savings realized and the pay cut inherent in your proposal) add up quickly. I'm just not sure that's a feasible option.  But in short, no, that question was not asked, and I think probably because it wouldn't cover the cost.

Comment: Including "training" (which costs far more than computers) in the cost of _keeping_ employees seems a bit unfair.

Comment: That is not a custom in the USA. USA has at will employment, so firings happen from tomorrow and you can easily get work. Union things, minimum wage and notice, these are all possible but not obligatory and not very common.

Comment: @Philippe something that is pretty common here is for a company to suggest employees, especially elder, to retire willingly and get a nice bonus for that. This way the costs you described are saved, and less employees are laid off. [Example](https://en.globes.co.il/en/article-teva-to-lay-off-200-in-israel-1001386895)

Comment: @GCCampbell "As I mentioned, our focus for this fiscal year and into the next is profitability and that, along with macroeconomic pressures led to today’s changes." Sounds like cost was the leading consideration to me.

Comment: @Philippe Yes, I'm aware the cost of benefits adds to the cost of employment, so everyone would have to take a deeper cut in their salary to compensate (or forgo benefits.) The numbers being big doesn't mean they shouldn't ask.

Comment: @peterh 'That's not the way we do it here' isn't how progress is made. Yes, I'm aware that the US operates on an at-will basis, however I vigorously disagree that it's easy to get work - That typically takes months in my experience, which is a long time to go without income, and the situation in tech is worse for those who are in traditionally disadvantaged groups, such as those of us over 50.

Answer (score -7):

Why can’t you have laid off the less valuable employees?

Comment: And why -4 score?

Comment: Probably because (emphasis added): "I hope that we can count on you to do everything possible to ease their transition, **beginning by not speculating as to who was cut and ‘why’**"

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid I am not asking why the employees that were laid off were laid off, I was asking what made them not choose other employees.

Comment: @TheEmptyStringPhotographer you chose a rather weird way to ask that. In particular, you're up front assigning a value to the remaining employees as "less"er than the ones that were laid off, which is surely a subjective measure of value that you personally hold rather than some specific metric that the company could realistically have used.

Comment: That comes under the "why" part though.

Answer (score -20):

The following will not be a question (as asked for in the initial question) but a commentary, even though, given the majority of the other responses, perhaps an unwelcome one.

I don't know any of you personally, but I am pretty sure almost all of you come from countries with a capitalist system of some sort in place. The fact that it is in place suggests, that a majority of people in your country - and, by extension, you - want to have this system. Otherwise you would have abolished it in one way or the other - elect parties which have abolition of capitalism on their agenda, start a revolution or whatever.

So, given that you prefer capitalism over other ways to organize production: a capitalist company has only a single goal: **to make as much money as possible for its owners**. Everything else is just means to an end - or outright folklore. A company dealing in tomatoes doesn't *want everybody to have good tomatoes* (even if their advertisements say so) but want to make money. Distributing and selling tomatoes are just the means to that end. If they find out that selling used toothpaste makes more money you can bet they switch products - their wish that *everybody has good tomatoes* notwithstanding.

I know, this introduction is getting long - but now I have reached the outcome stage:

This is your preferred system (capitalism) and this company works according to the laws this system has. If you go to a baseball match you don't get enraged if the teams play according to the rules of baseball and what follows from those. Why are you "disillusioned", "have lost trust" and all other sorts of things now? This company has always acted in the best interest of their profits - and for some time that meant having better customer support - and they continue to do so now.

Consider, just one example, all the banks who fired ("reduced", "right-sized", ...) their staff and replaced it with automats where basically *you* now do the work their staff used to do for you. Did they once say they valued you less as a customer, just because their service got lousier and lousier? No, they would never get tired to assure you how valuable you and your relationship to them are and how precious doing business with you is for them. But, alas, times are changing and they are, for crying out loud, forced to do what they have to ...

Does that sound familiar? Well, if it does, that is because it is. It is not only familiar, in fact it is absolutely the same.

You were - up to now - just in the lucky position not to feel the constrictions the system of production (capitalism) places on this specific company. Now you do. Would you have been not a customer of SE but a customer of a, say, grocery store, you would have noticed these constrictions long ago. Information technology was just so new that for a long time things were possible which aren't in other areas. Now, that IT has become a business like any other, the same rules apply.

Instead of "losing trust" you should lose your illusions aobut how a capitalist company in general - and this company in particular works. Actually, they have to work that way because the system is designed that way. Like in the example above: the baseball rules prescribe a certain way of playing it and if you don't follow this you are bound to lose game after game.

**Conclusion**
You have several options: you can vote with your feet and move on to become customer of another provider - like you can switch banks or insurance companies if you are dissatisfied with their service. Whereever you will end up, though, the same basic rules and restrictions will apply and your experience might be *gradually* better (or maybe just better suited to your personal preferences) but fundamentally the same.

You can also rethink your stance towards the company you are customer of: I, for instance, like to write and answer questions about some topics (German language, music theory, English language, ...) and I appreciate when I can search for and get information here about topics I am interested in. I don't need any "community manager" or other interaction with the site to achieve these goals. I also don't need to build up "trust" or whatever. If they don't like me here any more they can cancel my account and I will go elsewhere. They can also take away my "privileges", I don't need them. If I would need to transcend my existence and leave a legacy I can reproduce or write a book. I don't need recognition as a "personality" here on a website.

Comment: I'm not sure if what I'm gonna say is relevant to your answer... but your answer reminds me of my friend's answer in Ask Ubuntu Meta which talks about commons. Please read it: https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/18387/

Comment: Many companies do not have a focus on making as much money as possible - they actually consider that the company and their people exist within a society at large that should be considered as well.

Comment: That someone exists within a given... "capitalist system" or any other kind of system isn't evidence one supports such a system... and even if one does support it, that similarly doesn't mean they agree with pursuing actions blindly without any pause for considering consequences.

Comment: Tell me how you really feel about Atlas Shrugged.

Comment: I only skimmed your post, but my impression is "Capitalism is here. They're just doing capitalism. DEAL WITH IT or go somewhere else" and ... kinda? But that's a gross oversimplification. I agree they have to monetize and budget to survive (whether under capitalism, socialism, communism, or any money-driven economy), but umm ... that doesn't mean they have to be opaque, and it doesn't mean they have to be deaf to their community's (customers') concerns.

Comment: Re *"become customer of another provider"*: That presumes that there are viable alternatives. I don't think there is. Either they lack the [network effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_effect) or they are not real alternatives. [Quora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quora) is roamed by AI moderation bots of unspecified IQ (and is not a real alternative anyway). [DEV](https://dev.to/about) is [infested with blatant plagiarism](https://www.wagslane.dev/posts/collapsing-quality-of-devto/). -

Comment: cont' - [The Code Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Project) lacks the network effect. Codidact is lacking the network effect. [Reddit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reddit), maybe?

Comment: *"I live in [North Korea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Korea) and other failed states"* and being fluent in German is a rare combination.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum: I was asked where I live and "I live in North Korea" was my way of saying "This is none of your business". If there are "no viable alternatives" then this should - according to the many people bemoaning the state of affairs - be a great opportunity to start such an alternative. Most probably, though, all the outcry will result in ultimately people accepting the status quo and if that is the case then management has done the right thing - why spend money on CR if the people accept it being missing.

Comment: @Reed: I have only skimmed your reply, but from what I have not read I think you are mistaken. Are we now on a par of ignoring each other?

Comment: @KevinB: As I have argued, obviously a majority of the population supports it. If you don't, then do something about it. To "do something" doesn't actually mean downvoting the one pointing it out. That is just hypocrisy.

Comment: @JonCuster: just name one - relevant one, "my uncle Joes garage-based bicycle repair shop" doesn't count - of those "many companies". As far as I know the likes of Jeff Bezos or Elon Musk haven't become as rich as they are by giving to the poor but rather by screwing them over.

Comment: You seem to have unrealistic expectations of people. It’s easy to sit on the sidelines and critique inaction.

Comment: @KevinB: Why do I have "unrealistic expectations"? My prediction is that a lot off people will write here, vent their frustration, then continue to visit the site like nothing has happened. They just downvote what I wrote because they don't like to have that inaction pointed out to them. I disturbed their illusion of being well-meaning, socially active, community oriented, bla, yada, .... - which they aren't. If you want to *change* things, then work on that change - or accept that things are as they are. *I* wasn't the one raging all over about the evil management and their sinister plan.

Comment: Patagonia. REI. Ben & Jerry. Three well known companies.

Comment: I used capitalism, Adam Smith, invisible hand as arguments many times. The community answer was always massive downvotes, and hostile comment which clearly did not understand the post. I believe, you might think in capitalism but they do not. Because they do not understand what is it.

Comment: This overlooks a key part: The company is not itself providing the content it requires to be attractive. As such, they will have no business model without the content creators - who do this for free.|
A company going all capitalist should then, in turn, pay its contributors.

Comment: @bytepusher: This is exactly the central question: will the content creators stay away when the company cuts back on the staff dealing with these. Chances are that they will stay which makes the move - save costs without any adversary effect - justified. If indeed the content creators would leave then the move would be unwise, but since people write lengthy treatises here instead of just leaving I suppose the former alternative is more realistic than the latter.

Comment: leaving isn't the only option. I for one have cut back significantly on answers. I can't be bothered. Perhaps if I felt more engaged, I would. Meanwhile, I've turned to others, often pre-existing alternatives for my needs. Yes, I do check in on occasion. But I hardly contribute anymore.

Comment: @bytepusher: This is exactly what I meant by "rethink the stance twoards the company". There are a lot of people here who seem to define themselves in terms of reputation and badges and if the site starts to tank this should feel for them like their existence is in danger. I suppose this is where all the downvotes come from - but, since I am not here for a popularity contest, I don't care. You are welcome to downvote my answer if you haven't done so already.

Comment: Given that many of the complaints are roughly "the company is spending money on things that will not help their product succeed and not spending money on far cheaper things that will", it is hard to see how this is inherent to a capitalist system.  Surely a capitalist would want to do the cheaper, more effective things.

Comment: @RyanM: So, basically you (and the other complainers you summed up) think the company is badly run? Then, by all means, buy it and run it better! This is also capitalism: you can buy anything and everything given you have the money and if you don't have the money none of your complaints are worth anything. You can - just for instance - think Amazon treats its staff very badly all day long, but in the end you can either buy Amazon and change it to your liking - or shut up. Or you change the system which only leaves these two alternatives, see my second paragraph.

Comment: @bakunin, your profile mentions your superstition. I think a lot of the people who visit meta.SE and who don't like seeing layoffs or dread the consequences share a similar superstition, and bemoan the events exactly because they feel the result may be that the "helping others" part may suffer from it, and the world will become less better than it could be. And at the same time, they also have the understanding that it might not even be such a good idea for business. (They might be wrong, of course, but that's always a possibility.)

Comment: @ilkkachu: First off: building walls is of course the hallmark of a terrorist regime: the US and their wall on the southern border, the EU with their many walls on their borders, Israel with their wall, ... - but wait, these are all the harbingers of freedom, no? Second: yes, exactly! For some time the citizens of Eastern Germany were not dissatisfied enough - and once they were they indeed did change their system. Exactly as you said. So, what was wrong with what I wrote, except that I tried to analyze the situation instead of crying out "booo, what a shame!"

Comment: @ilkkachu: Where have I "complained" about anything?? I have analyzed, what happens. If you don't like what happens: you are free to leave - and if enough people follow your example I bet SE will change course. This is exactly their reasoning: *we cut our expenses for the community and people will rage all day but in the end they will stay and we have the same as before for less costs.*" If not "everything is as before" they will change course, but not any earlier.

Comment: @ilkkachu: where exactly was the "grossly overgeneralized assumptions" exactly? And do you have any proof for that statement, except for your wish that it may be so? Please do me a favor: just downvote whatever I write or ahve written and spare me the drama.

Comment: @ilkkachu: I have made no claim about what "pretty much everyone thinks", but I have made a claim about the origin of most of SEs contributors. The next sentence has "the majority of people in your country" as a subject. If you can't understand the difference between "the majority of you" and that you should go back to school - I am in no position to teach you basic reading comprehension. For my motive: just assume some sinister deep state conspiracy and be done. Just as a hint: if you participate in an election you inherently accept the outcome.

Comment: @ilkkachu: I haven't picked on your phrasing but your obvious inability to understand what I wrote and exemplified this inability by showing how you couldn't even repeat what I said. I'll say it again: if you participate in an election you inherently accept its outcome - even if it is not to your liking. As for going to sleep: if vilifying me helps you sleep better then more power to you - and good riddance.

Comment: @bakunin The SE is evil, and the SE is so evil because its founders are exactly so evil. As you are only sitting shocked and try to understand WTF was again this irrational hostility, imagine that you are just talking with Joel Spolsky himself. It simply a cultural difference: for these new yorker guys, this is normal. For the rest of the world, it is not. This is why they don't understand, why their site is still criticised for its evil attitude. For them, in their culture, this all is pretty okay. They are going so far that now the free market eliminates them and they still don't understand.

Comment: @bakunin I think, not that is the interesting part of the story. The interesting part is that, while they are unthinkable evil, still they made this site. If you had any programming problem, >90% that the SE has the answer. They did it. Despite that they are evil, they have actually helped me to solve *a lot* of IRL problems, my English became much better because of the SE and so my culture of argumentation. I wasted an unthinkable amount of time, but I have also learned a lot. I remember the serpent, from the Book of Genesis. While they are surely human, they are also... like that serpent.

Answer (score -29):

To the downvoters, first I would suggest to think about a bit, what had you done if you needed to pay their salary every month. Note: if you live in a better part of the world, their salary is about twice of yours. (Source: glassdoor.com ) In lesser developed regions, they might earn 20 times more.

The people laid off were working for a company in a region with one of the best job options of the world, and their CV starts now with a well known name. You have absolutely no reason to fear for them.

Do not think that they had any problem to find a new job or a new living.

Second, the people laid off now, they were once also employed by the company. It could happened only because the company has seen good representants of its ideas and values in them.

You, dear community, have just voted these ideas and values with a -177 score. Being fired by the company, that does not mean that they had followed so much different ideas and values as the company, it only means that the company had no money for their salary.

And, as many of you point to that in other answers, exactly these ideas and values has lead the company to this financial situation.

Comment: Do you expect people to upvote the news that people have lost their job? Do you find it useful that one of the spokespeople doesn't even have a stackexchange profile? Do you agree with the statement that the "community isn't going anywhere"?

Comment: @Sayse 1) No. But I expect them to understand, they live better without a job as most downvoters with it. 2) and 3): No. But I am here since 11 years and I have found here the most evil internet community ever. That is the fault of the community, of the company, and of the now fired guys, too. I you would say that the company is evil, that I would fully agree - problem is that the SE community and the fired guys are evil, too.

Comment: you're conflating things here. the people who were laid off made up part of the company, yes, but when you refer to the decision made by the company that decision was not made by the people who were laid off. the decision was made by upper leadership. people are upset by what leadership did, not what the laid off employees did

Comment: @intcreator Yes, people were fired because the upper leadership wanted it so. That is evidential, and that is irrelevant. I only say, that the company is evil, its employee (at least the ones I could know) were not lesser evil, and so also the community collected here is very, very, very evil. In my opinion, the SE community is the worst internet community in this sense, and I am not alone with this opinion. This is why SE is losing to the ChatGPT and to google. On these reasons, I can not feel sad for the laid off guys. Note, the barely covered hostility is well visible also in your comment.

Comment: @intcreator If you would like to at least understand, why people have a critical tone to this site, company and community, I suggest take a look [here](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=stack+overflow).

Comment: It does not appear to me as if answers were concerned mainly with the people who were laid off. (I guess we can all agree that being laid off sucks, and also that even in the current job market, which is not as rosy as it was a while ago, these particular people have a good chance of landing on their feet.) Rather, people seem to be concerned with the effects of the layoffs *on the community*. Of course we don't know why people voted on the original post, but my guess would be that again, it's for the likely impact *on the community*. So I think you may be barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I think, that is nothing unusual what has happened, and there is nothing unusual in the attitude of the company to us. Possibly they also overestimate the quality decrease of the life of the fired guys, again I would point to glassdoor.

Comment: @intcreator I reformulated the second part. I think the logic is clear but not obvious, so I added more details.

Comment: "The company had no money for their salary" **citation needed**

Comment: @Conrado Can you imagine any other reason of a mass layoff? Btw, I see no reason to dig out references for you, because it is clearly visible that it won't change anything.

Comment: Yes, I can, but there is no need to imagine: the CEO's blog post states that the company is  focusing "on a path to profitability" and "taking steps to spend less". First, however, it mentions "**monumental efforts to successfully launch OverflowAI**", which is hardly possible if the company has no money for salaries.

Comment: @Conrado These are unrelated. Instead of hair-splitting, nitpicking, just read the other answers and tease them. I think our talk ends now.

Comment: "what had you done if you needed to pay their salary every month" - I would start by not hiring way too many sales people if I can't afford them. I would also start by not investing in AI Products when my clients don't like AI. I would also start by not selling the company to Prosus, so I could keep my management autonomy.

Comment: [Cont] - Layoffs like those can happen, but on the Stack Overflow's case it is transparent that what happened was a _major_ management fumble. We are upset with the layoffs because something on the business plan of the company had a major issue that ended up causing this horrible situation.

Comment: We had several cases of companies hiring too much and them having to downsize greatly a soon afterwards because they overshoot hiring way before the hiring spree on Stack Overflow took place. Management was either overconfident, incompetent, or outright malicious (by aiming at the prosus sale and nothing more). We aren't upset because this situation happened. We are upset because of the "whys" this situation happened.

Comment: @T.Sar I think, what the company is doing, needs about 10-50 people. Not 500. Thus, overhiring is likely, not today but a long, long ago [about the last public employee list in 2017 ](https://web.archive.org/web/20170424052416/http://stackoverflow.com/company/team) had already maybe a 300 employee, from most of them no mortal has ever heard anything. The [linkedin](https://www.linkedin.com/company/stack-overflow/people/) has 700 guys now, again no mortal knows anything what could they do.

Comment: @perth previous bad management is no excuse for current or future bad management.

Comment: @T.Sar Yes, I agree. I think, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tQt11xA69tY) might have happened. I am since 25 years in the IT. I think we can roughly put together, what a company is really doing, and how big is it. I think the SE is about 10x bigger as it should be. And that explains a lot about their... secrecy. No employee, including the leads, has the spine to say anything, all of them have a Damocles' sword on his neck. And that makes the work at the company probably extremely unpleasant, fearful. However, they pay really a lot, even on USA customs... pack these together...